# How to output something in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am running a PowerShell script from within a batch file. The script fetches a web page and checks whether the page's content is the string "OK".

The PowerShell script returns an error level to the batch script.

The batch script is executed by [ScriptFTP](http://www.scriptftp.com), an FTP automation program. If an error occurs, I can have ScriptFTP send the full console output to the administrator via E-Mail.

In the PowerShell script, I would like to output the return value from the web site if it is not "OK", so the error message gets included in the console output, and thus in the status mail.

I am new to PowerShell and not sure which output function to use for this. I can see three:

- Write-Host
- Write-Output
- Write-Error

What would be the right thing to use to write to the Windows equivalent of `stdout`?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Simply outputting something is PowerShell is a thing of beauty - and one its greatest strengths. For example, the common Hello, World! application is reduced to a single line:

```
"Hello, World!"
```

It creates a string object, assigns the aforementioned value, and being the last item on the command pipeline it calls the `.toString()` method and outputs the result to `STDOUT` (by default). A thing of beauty.

The other `Write-*` commands are specific to outputting the text to their associated streams, and have their place as such.

Comment: That's not really what happens. It's a string literal expression and the only thing in its pipeline. Thus it's equivalent to `"Hello, World!" | Out-Host`. `Out-Host` on the other hand sends objects to the PowerShell host for display and its implementation is dependent on the host. The console host sends them to the standard output handle (passing through `Out-Default` along the way), indeed. PowerShell ISE displays them in its output pane, however, and other hosts may do yet other things entirely.

Comment: Objects also don't get blindly converted to string, but pass through a _formatter_ which decides on what to do with them. That's why you see `Get-ChildItem`'s output coming in a table form, for example, and results with many properties (e.g. WMI) default to `Format-List` instead.

Answer (score 146):

I think in this case you will need [Write-Output](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx).

If you have a script like

```
Write-Output "test1";
Write-Host "test2";
"test3";
```

then, if you call the script with redirected output, something like `yourscript.ps1 > out.txt`, you will get `test2` on the screen `test1\ntest3\n` in the "out.txt".

Note that "test3" and the Write-Output line will always append a new line to your text and there is no way in PowerShell to stop this (that is, `echo -n` is impossible in PowerShell with the native commands). If you want (the somewhat basic and easy in [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)) functionality of `echo -n` then see [samthebest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038181/how-to-output-something-in-powershell/11901810#11901810).

If a batch file runs a PowerShell command, it will most likely capture the Write-Output command. I have had "long discussions" with system administrators about what should be written to the console and what should not. We have now agreed that the only information if the script executed successfully or died has to be `Write-Host`'ed, and everything that is the script's author might need to know about the execution (what items were updated, what fields were set, et cetera) goes to Write-Output. This way, when you submit a script to the system administrator, he can easily `runthescript.ps1 >someredirectedoutput.txt` and see on the screen, if everything is OK. Then send the "someredirectedoutput.txt" back to the developers.

Answer (score 18):

I think the following is a good exhibit of Echo vs. [Write-Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Write-Host). Notice how test() actually returns an array of ints, not a single int as one could easily be led to believe.

```
function test {
    Write-Host 123
    echo 456 # AKA 'Write-Output'
    return 789
}

$x = test

Write-Host "x of type '$($x.GetType().name)' = $x"

Write-Host "`$x[0] = $($x[0])"
Write-Host "`$x[1] = $($x[1])"
```

Terminal output of the above:

```
123
x of type 'Object[]' = 456 789
$x[0] = 456
$x[1] = 789
```

Comment: I can look at this all day... But why is  `$x = test` only printing `123` and not also `456`?

Comment: Write-Output (or echo) writes the specified objects to the pipeline. If Write-Output is the last command in the pipeline, the objects are displayed in the console. Here it is the 2nd last and is there being piped down to the return statement and added the array

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 8):

You can use any of these in your scenario since they write to the default streams (output and error). If you were piping output to another commandlet you would want to use [Write-Output](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx), which will eventually terminate in [Write-Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849877.aspx).

This article describes the different output options: [PowerShell O is for Output](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/powershell-abcs-o-is-for-output)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Goodness, this is *complicated*. If Write-host is some sort of endpoint or flushing function, I will try and go with that and report back.

Answer (score 8):

> What would be the right thing to use to write to the Windows equivalent of stdout?

**In *effect*, but very *unfortunately***, both **Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core as of v7.2, send *all* of their 6(!) [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) to *stdout*** when **called *from the outside*, via PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)**.

- See [GitHub issue #7989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7989#issuecomment-430854508) for a discussion of this problematic behavior, which likely won't get fixed, so as to preserve backward compatibility.
- **In practice, this means that *whatever PowerShell stream you send output to* will be seen as *stdout* output by an external caller:**

  - E.g., if you run the following from `cmd.exe`, you'll see *no* output, because the stdout redirection to `NUL` applies equally to all PowerShell streams:

    - `C:\>powershell -noprofile -command "Write-Error error!" >NUL`
  - However - curiously - **if you *redirect stderr*, PowerShell *does* send its error stream to stderr**, so that with `2>` you *can* capture the error-stream output selectively; the following outputs just `'hi'` - the success-stream output - while capturing the error-stream output in file `err.txt`:

    - `C:\>powershell -noprofile -command "'hi'; Write-Error error!" 2>err.txt`

The ***desirable* behavior** is:

- Send PowerShell's ***success output stream* (number `1`) to *stdout***.
- Send output from ***all other streams* to *stderr***, which is the only option, given that *between* processes only *2* output streams exist - stdout (standard output) for *data*, and stderr (standard error) for error messages *and* all other types of messages - such as status information - that aren't *data*.
- **It's advisable to make this distinction in your code, even though it currently isn't being respected**.

---

***Inside* PowerShell**:

- **`Write-Host`** is **for *display* output**, and ***bypasses* the success output stream** - as such, its output can neither be (directly) captured in a variable nor suppressed nor redirected.

  - Its original intent was simply to create user feedback and create simple, console-based user interfaces (colored output).
  - Due to the prior inability to be captured or redirected, PowerShell version 5 made `Write-Host` write to the newly introduced *information stream* (number `6`), so since then it *is* possible to capture and redirect `Write-Host` output.
- **`Write-Error`** is meant for **writing *non-terminating* errors to the *error stream*** (number `2`); conceptually, the error stream is the equivalent of stderr.
- **`Write-Output`** writes to the ***success [output] stream*** (number `1`), which is conceptually equivalent to stdout; it is **the stream to write *data* (results) to.**

  - However, **explicit use of `Write-Output` is rarely needed** due to PowerShell's ***implicit output* feature**:

    - **Output from any command or expression that isn't explicitly captured, suppressed or redirected is *automatically* sent to the success stream**; e.g., `Write-Output "Honey, I'm $HOME"` and `"Honey, I'm $HOME"` are equivalent, with the latter not only being more concise, but also faster.
    - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

```
Write-Host "Found file - " + $File.FullName -ForegroundColor Magenta
```

Magenta can be one of the "System.ConsoleColor" enumerator values - Black, DarkBlue, DarkGreen, DarkCyan, DarkRed, DarkMagenta, DarkYellow, Gray, DarkGray, Blue, Green, Cyan, Red, Magenta, Yellow, White.

The `+ $File.FullName` is optional, and shows how to put a variable into the string.

Answer (score 2):

You simply cannot get PowerShell to ommit those pesky newlines. There is no script or cmdlet that does this.

Of course Write-Host is absolute nonsense because you can't redirect/pipe from it!  You simply have to write your own:

```
using System;

namespace WriteToStdout
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args != null)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Join(" ", args));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E.g.

```
PS C:\> writetostdout finally I can write to stdout like echo -n
finally I can write to stdout like echo -nPS C:\>
```

Comment: You could do this in powershell itself. [System.Console]::Write("stringy")
However you won't be able to redirect it at all in powershell.

Comment: Sure you can.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896258/how-to-output-text-without-newline-in-powershell)