# Avoiding newline in write-output

Tags: powershell

I want to collect all output from my script in a log file and must use write-output instaed of write-host.

`Write-Output "Server:" $a` looks like

`Server:

foo`.

Do I really have to write to write
`write-output $("sfdghk:" + $a)` to get `Server:Foo`

Thanks 
-jt

Comment: `Write-Output "Server:$a"`

Comment: @empo:  You should submit this as an answer.  In my opinion, it's more direct and relevant than the only answer so far.

Answer (score 15):

Found somewhere on the Internet:

```
Write-Output "Server: $($a)"
```

Works great in my code.

Comment: For this example, the `$(...)` construct is redundant, as it says to treat everything inside the parentheses as script rather than text.  Since the `$a` is already interpreted and inserted in quoted strings, the wrapper doesn't need to be added.

`Write-Output "Server: $a"`
...will work fine.

Use the wrapper `$()` when you are trying to access methods or properties of variables.

`$a = "I like eggs."
Write-Output "Character count: $($a.length)"` would print out `I like eggs..length` without the `$(...)` wrapper.

Comment: thank you, you save me a day!  I think this is powershell design problem, it shouldn't make the way so different then another script lang.

Answer (score 9):

9 hours ... I start an answer.

In Powershell everything you manipulate is an object.

so "Server:" is an object, $a is an object

```
PS> "server :".gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

`Write-output` is a CmdLet that put object in a kind of list (a pipe) to be used by other CmdLets or scripts. So there is not a really a newline between "Server:" and "foo". It's the way the console show you a list (an array) of objects. As you can see here under :

```
PS> $a = "foo"
PS> (Write-Output "Server :" $a).gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Clearly it's an abstract here, but I hope it can make you understand.

Answer (score 8):

```
Write-Output "Server: $a"
Write-Output ("Server: {0}" -f $a)
Write-Output ("Server: " + $a)
```

If you want to collect the output from a script into a log file, consider using `Start-Transcript`.  It logs every command and all PowerShell output to a file.  It doesn't log anything sent to stdout, however, so if you're using any legacy commands, you'll have to pipe their output to `Write-Host`:

```
Start-Transcript C:\logs\mylog.txt
Write-Host "Server: " $a
ping | Write-Host
```

Comment: PowerShell's _equivalent_ to stdout is its _success output stream_ and things sent there _do_ get logged. `Write-Host` _in the past_ didn't write to _stdout_ but rather printed _directly to the console_, which is why such output didn't show up in transcripts. In PSv5+, however, `Write-Host` / `Out-Host` now write to the newly introduced _information stream_ (as does the new `Write-Information` cmdlet), which now _does_ get logged. You can either use `$null = ...` to suppress output completely, or, to emulate PSv4- `Write-Host` behavior in this context, use `$host.ui.WriteLine()`.

Answer (score 8):

There's good information in the existing answers, but let me attempt a pragmatic summary:

- When printing to the *console* or *redirecting to a file*, **`Write-Output` separates *multiple* arguments by a newline each**.
- Therefore, **in order to produce *single-line* output, you must "pre-assemble" the parts to output into a *single* string** that you pass as a *single* argument.

  - [Aaron Jensen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12220779/45375) shows you 3 alternative ways of doing that.
- Except to suppress enumeration of collections, **you generally do not need to use `Write-Output` explicitly**, because PowerShell *by default* sends anything that is not captured in a variable or redirected elsewhere or sent through the pipeline to the *[success] output stream* (which `Write-Output` also writes to); thus, in the case at hand, the following is sufficient:

```
"Server: $a"  # what this expandable string expands to is *implicitly* output
```

---

What may be confusing is that the **`Write-Host` cmdlet acts differently**, but it's important to note that it has a **different purpose**.

```
# IMPORTANT: Do not use Write-Host to output *data*; only use it to write
#            directly to the host (console).
PS> Write-Host "Server:"     $a    # multiple spaces used on purpose
Server: srv1
```

**`Write-Host`, unlike `Write-Output`, separates multiple arguments by a *single space* each.**
There are other important differences, which are summarized in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45829541/45375) of mine.

---

Given the generic title of the question, let's also address **how to suppress a *trailing* newline**:

- For printing **to the *console only***, you can use `Write-Host -NoNewline`.
- **With *data* output**, be it via `Write-Output`, implicit output, or from another command:

  - You *cannot* prevent a trailing newline when the output is sent to the *console*.
  - Unfortunately, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.0.0, you ***cannot* prevent a trailing newline when sending text to *external* programs via the *pipeline*** - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5974).
  - In PSv5+, however, you ***can* prevent a trailing newline** when **capturing output in a *file***, by using `Out-File -NoNewline` or `Set-Content -NoNewline` (in PSv4-, you must use the .NET Framework directly); by contrast, redirecting to a file with `>` does append a trailing newline.

    - Caveat: If you're outputting *multiple* objects, `-NoNewline` not only suppresses a *trailing* newline, but also newlines *between* these objects.
    - For the differences between `Out-File` and `Set-Content` and when to choose which, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246434/45375) of mine.

Comment: In case you need to use `args[n]` you can't use the `"$args[-1]"` but have to use the formatted form, like this: `Write-Output ("{0} \`t{1}" -f $args[-1],$PWD) | Out-File -Append $HOME/.somefile`.

Comment: @not2qubit: As an isolated command argument, you can use `$args[-1]` as-is: `& { Write-Output $args[-1] } one two`. To embed it in a larger string, you need `$(...)`: `& { Write-Output "$($args[-1])!" } one two` - see PowerShell's [string interpolation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).