# Output ("echo") a variable to a text file

Tags: powershell, file-io

I'm running a PowerShell script against many servers, and it is logging output to a text file.

I'd like to capture the server the script is currently running on. So far I have:

```
$file = "\\server\share\file.txt"
$computername = $env:computername

$computername | Add-Content -Path $file
```

This last line adds question marks in the output file. Oops.

How do I output a variable to a text file in PowerShell?

Comment: you last two lines works fine on my computer.

Comment: What is the value of $env:computername? How are you viewing the file? What encoding are you using?

Comment: $env:computername returns my local computername as it should.  Tested in the shell.  It's just not being passed correctly to the test file.  No encoding specified.  Typing the file out in the shell.

Comment: Does your computer name have non ascii characters in it?

Comment: No, no non-ascii characters.  Found the answer, posted it.  Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found that

```
$computername = $env:computername
```

works to get a computer name, but sending `$computername` to a file via [Add-Content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849859.aspx) doesn't work.

I also tried `$computername.Value`.

Instead, if I use

```
$computername = get-content env:computername
```

I can send it to a text file using

```
$computername | Out-File $file
```

Comment: There is _no_ difference between `Get-Content env:computername` and `$env:computername`. Your question uses `Add-Content`, whereas your answer uses `Out-File`, which are distinct cmdlets with distinct default encoding behaviors. Aside from coding defaults, `Add-Content` _appends to a preexisting file_, whereas `Out-File` always creates a _new_ file / truncates (overwrites) an existing one.

Answer (score 91):

The simplest Hello World example...

```
$hello = "Hello World"
$hello | Out-File c:\debug.txt
```

Comment: Simple indeed, but it doesn't address the OP's misconceptions around `Add-Content` and what character encoding issues come into play.

Answer (score 32):

<sup>Note: The answer below is written from the **perspective of *Windows PowerShell***.

However, it **applies to the cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)  as well**, ***except*** that the latter - commendably - **consistently defaults to *BOM-less UTF-8*** as the character encoding, which is the most widely compatible one across platforms and cultures.</sup>.

---

To complement [bigtv's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20599208/45375) helpful answer with a more concise alternative and background information:

```bash
# > $file is effectively the same as | Out-File $file
# Objects are written the same way they display in the console.
# Default character encoding is UTF-16LE (mostly 2 bytes per char.), with BOM.
# Use Out-File -Encoding <name> to change the encoding.
$env:computername > $file

# Set-Content calls .ToString() on each object to output.
# Default character encoding is "ANSI" (culture-specific, single-byte).
# Use Set-Content -Encoding <name> to change the encoding.
# Use Set-Content rather than Add-Content; the latter is for *appending* to a file.
$env:computername | Set-Content $file
```

When **outputting to a text file**, you have **2 fundamental choices** that use **different object representations** and, in Windows PowerShell (as opposed to PowerShell *Core*), also employ **different *default* character encodings**:

- [`Out-File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) (or `>`) / `Out-File -Append` (or `>>`):

  - **Suitable for output objects of *any* type**, because PowerShell's default output formatting is applied to the output objects.

    - In other words: **you get the same output as when printing to the *console***.
  - The **default encoding**, which can be changed with the `-Encoding` parameter, is **`Unicode`**, which is [UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) in which **most characters are encoded as *2* bytes**. The advantage of a Unicode encoding such as UTF-16LE is that it is a *global* alphabet, capable of encoding all characters from *all* human languages.

    - In **PSv5.1+**, you can **change the encoding used by `>` and `>>`**, via the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` preference variable, taking advantage of the fact that `>` and `>>` are now effectively aliases of `Out-File` and `Out-File -Append`. To change to UTF-8 (invariably *with* a BOM, in Windows PowerShell), for instance, use:
      `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding']='UTF8'`
- [`Set-Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) / [`Add-Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content):

  - For writing **strings** and instances of **types known to have meaningful string representations**, such as the .NET primitive data types (Booleans, integers, ...).

    - **`.psobject.ToString()` method is called on each output object**, which results in meaningless representations for types that don't explicitly implement a meaningful representation; `[hashtable]` instances are an example:
      `@{ one = 1 } | Set-Content t.txt` writes literal `System.Collections.Hashtable` to `t.txt`, which is the result of `@{ one = 1 }.ToString()`.
  - The **default encoding**, which can be changed with the `-Encoding` parameter, is **`Default`**, which is the system's active **ANSI code page**, i.e. the **single-byte *culture-specific* legacy encoding** for non-Unicode applications, which is most commonly [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).
    Note that the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) currently incorrectly claims that ASCII is the default encoding.
  - Note that **`Add-Content`'s purpose is to *append*** content to an *existing file*, and it is only equivalent to `Set-Content` if the target file doesn't exist yet.
    If the file exists and is nonempty, `Add-Content` - unlike `Out-File -Append` / `>>` - **tries to *match the existing encoding***.

`Out-File` / `>` / `Set-Content` / `Add-Content` **all act culture-*sensitively***, i.e., they produce representations suitable for the current culture (locale), if available (though custom formatting data is free to define its own, culture-invariant representation - see [`Get-Help about_format.ps1xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml)).
This **contrasts with PowerShell's string expansion** (string interpolation in double-quoted strings), which is **culture-*invariant*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) of mine.

As for **performance**:

- Since **`Set-Content`** doesn't have to apply default formatting to its input, it **performs better**, and therefore is the preferred choice if your input is composed of *strings* and/or of objects whose default stringification via the standard .NET `.ToString()` method is sufficient.

---

As for **the OP's symptom with `Add-Content`**:

Since `$env:COMPUTERNAME` cannot contain non-ASCII characters (or *verbatim* `?` characters), `Add-Content`'s addition to the file should *not* result in `?` characters, and the likeliest explanation is that the `?` instances were part of the *preexisting content* in output file `$file`, which `Add-Content` *appended to*.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample code seems to be OK. Thus, the root problem needs to be dug up somehow. Let's eliminate chance for typos in the script. First off, make sure you put `Set-Strictmode -Version 2.0` in the beginning of your script. This will help you to catch misspelled variable names. Like so,

```
# Test.ps1
set-strictmode -version 2.0 # Comment this line and no error will be reported.
$foo = "bar"
set-content -path ./test.txt -value $fo # Error! Should be "$foo"

PS C:\temp> .\test.ps1
The variable '$fo' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At C:\temp\test.ps1:3 char:40
+ set-content -path ./test.txt -value $fo <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (fo:Token) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

The next part about question marks sounds like you have a problem with Unicode. What's the output when you type the file with Powershell like so,

```
$file = "\\server\share\file.txt"
cat $file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy one:

```
$myVar > "c:\myfilepath\myfilename.myextension"
```

You can also try:

```
Get-content "c:\someOtherPath\someOtherFile.myextension" > "c:\myfilepath\myfilename.myextension"
```