# Prevent trailing newline in PowerShell Out-File command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How do I prevent PowerShell's [Out-File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Out-File) command from appending a newline after the text it outputs?

For example, running the following command produces a file with contents "TestTest\r\n" rather than just "TestTest".

```
"TestTest" | Out-File -encoding ascii test.txt
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In PowerShell 5.0+, you would use:

```
"TestTest" | Out-File -encoding ascii test.txt -NoNewline
```

But in earlier versions you simply can't with that cmdlet.

Try this:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($FilePath,"TestTest",[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
```

Comment: Use append switch as well to avoid overwriting whole file .i.e 
"TestTest" | Out-File -encoding ascii test.txt -NoNewline -Append

Comment: unfortunately WriteAllText always rewrites the target file, so it's not useful for continuous writing into log file.

Answer (score 20):

To *complement* [briantist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35279910/45375) re `-NoNewline`:

The following applies not just to `Out-File`, but analogously to `Set-Content` / `Add-Content` as well; as stated, `-NoNewline` requires PSv5+.

Note that **`-NoNewline`** means that with ***multiple* objects to output**, it is not just a *trailing* newline (line break) that is suppressed, but *any* newlines.

In other words: The **string representations of the input objects are directly concatenated, without a separator (terminator)**.

Therefore, the following commands result in the same file contents (`TestTest` without a trailing newline):

```bash
# Single input string
"TestTest" | Out-File -encoding ascii test.txt -NoNewline

# Equivalent command: 2-element array of strings that are directly concatenated.
"Test", "Test" | Out-File -encoding ascii test.txt -NoNewline
```

In order to **place newlines only *between*, but not also *after*** the output objects, you must **join the objects with newlines explicitly**:

```bash
"Test", "Test" -join [Environment]::NewLine |
  Out-File -encoding ascii test.txt -NoNewline
```

<sup>`[Environment]::NewLine` is the platform-appropriate newline sequence (CRLF on Windows, LF on Unix-like platforms); you can also produce either sequence explicitly, if needed, with `` "`r`n" `` and `` "`n" ``</sup>

**Caveat**:

The above `-join` solution implicitly converts the input objects to strings, if they aren't already and does so by calling the .NET `.ToString()` method on each object. This often yields a different representation than the one that `Out-File` would directly create, because `Out-File` uses PowerShell's *default output formatter*; for instance, compare the outputs of `(Get-Date).ToString()` and just `Get-Date`.

**If your input comprises only strings and/or non-strings whose `.ToString()` representation is satisfactory**, the above solution works, but note that it is then **generally preferable to use the `Set-Content` cmdlet**, which applies the same stringification implicitly.
For a complete discussion of the differences between `Out-File` and `Set-Content`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246434/45375).

If your input has non-strings that do you want to be formatted as they would print to the console, there is actually no simple solution: while you can use `Out-String` to create per-object string representations with the default formatter, `Out-String`'s lack of `-NoNewline` (as of v5.1; [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3684) suggests introducing it) would invariably yield trailing newlines.

Answer (score 0):

To complement briantist's and mklement0's helpful answers re *-NoNewline*:

I created this little function to replace the *-NoNewLine* parameter of *Out-File* in previous versions of powershell.

**Note: In my case it was for a .csv file with 7 lines (Days of the week and some more values)**

```
## Receive the value we want to add and "yes" or "no" depending on whether we want to 
put the value on a new line or not.
function AddValueToLogFile ($value, $NewLine) {
    ## If the log file exists:
    if (Test-path $Config.LogPath) {
        ## And we don't want to add a new line, the value is concatenated at the end.
        if ($NewLine -eq "no") {
            $file = Get-Content -Path $Config.LogPath 
            ## If the file has more than one line
            if ($file -is [array]) {
                $file[-1]+= ";" + $value
            }
            ## if the file only has one line
            else {
                $file +=  ";" + $value
            }
            $file | Out-File -FilePath $Config.LogPath
        }
        ## If we want to insert a new line the append parameter is used.
        elseif ($NewLine -eq "yes") {
            $value | Out-File -Append -FilePath $Config.LogPath
        }
    }
    ## If the log file does not exist it is passed as a value
    elseif (!(Test-path $Config.LogPath)) {
        $value | Out-File -FilePath $Config.LogPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to write array of line to file without trailing newline, you can do as following:

```
# prepare content, 5 lines
$arrayOfLines = 1..5 | % { "line $_" }
# display
$arrayOfLines

# save all but the last one
$arrayOfLines | select -SkipLast 1 > .\newfile.txt
# save the last one, with -NoNewline
$arrayOfLines[-1] | out-file -NoNewline -Append .\newfile.txt
```