# How can I prevent additional newlines with set-content while keeping existing ones when saving in UTF8?

Tags: powershell, utf-8

I have a small powershell script which reads a document with UTF8 encoding, makes some replacements in it and saves it back which looks like this:

```
(Get-Content $path) -Replace "myregex","replacement" | Set-Content $path2 -Encoding utf8
```

This will create a new file with the right encoding and right contents but there are additional new line characters at the end. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35279910/197371) and many others, I am told to either:

1. Add the parameter `-NoNewLine` to `Set-Content`
2. Use `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($path2,$content,[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)`

Both solutions remove the trailing new lines... **and every other new lines in the file**.

Is there a way to *both*:

1. Remove the trailing new lines while saving the file.
2. Keep the existing new lines in my file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[IO.File]::WriteAllText()` assumes that `$content` is a single string, but `Get-Content` produces an array of strings (and removes the line breaks from the end of each line/string). Mangling that string array into a single string joins the strings using the `$OFS` character (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23067832/1630171)).

To avoid this behavior you need to ensure that `$content` already is a single string when it's passed to `WriteAllText()`. There are various ways to do that, for instance:

- Use `Get-Content -Raw` (PowerShell v3 or newer):

  ```
  $content = (Get-Content $path -Raw) -replace 'myregex', 'replacement'
  ```
- Pipe the output through `Out-String`:

  ```
  $content = (Get-Content $path | Out-String) -replace 'myregex', 'replacement' -replace '\r\n$'
  ```

  Note, however, that `Out-String` (just like `Set-Content`) adds a trailing line break, as was pointed out in the comments. You need to remove that with a second replacement operation.
- Join the array with the `-join` operator:

  ```
  $content = (Get-Content $path) -replace 'myregex', 'replacement' -join "`r`n"
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and different options to handle that. The `-Raw` parameter was the answer for me. I didn't want to force a type of new line with `-join` operator but rather keep the same from the original file. When I tested the `Out-String` option, I still had new line at the end of the file. I wonder if I did something wrong...

Comment: @MarcelGosselin: Regrettably, `Out-String` _always_ appends a trailing newline, and doesn't support `-NoNewline` as of PSv5.1: `(Out-String -InputObject 'a') -match '^a\r?\n$'` returns `$true`. I've created [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3684) to suggest adding `-NoNewline` to `Out-String`.

Comment: My mistake. Totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 7):

To complement [Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43743183/45375):

Using **`Set-Content -NoNewline` (PSv5+) is an option, but only if you pass the output as a *single* string with *embedded* newlines**, which `Get-Content -Raw` can do:

```
(Get-Content -Raw $path) -replace 'myregex', 'replacement' |  
  Set-Content -NoNewline $path2 -Encoding utf8
```

Note, however, that the semantics of `-replace` change with the use of `-Raw`: now a *single*
`-replace` operation is performed on a *multi-line* string (the entire file contents) - as opposed to line-individual operations with an *array* as the LHS.

Also note that `-Raw` will preserve the trailing-newline-or-not status of the input.

If you want the line-by-line semantics and/or want to ensure that the output's final line has no trailing newline (even if the input file had one), use `Get-Content` without `-Raw`, and then `-join`:

```
(Get-Content $path) -replace 'myregex', 'replacement' -join [Environment]::NewLine |  
  Set-Content -NoNewline $path2 -Encoding utf8
```

The above uses the platform-appropriate newline character(s) on output, but note that there's no guarantee that the input file used the same.

---

As for **what you tried**:

As you've observed, **`Set-Content -NoNewline` with an *array* of strings causes *all* strings to be concatenated *without a separator*** - unlike what one might expect, `-NoNewline` doesn't just omit a *trailing* newline:

```
 > 'one', 'two' | Set-Content -NoNewline t.txt; Get-Content -Raw t.txt
 onetwo  # Strings were directly concatenated.
```

<sup>Note: Newlines *embedded* in input strings are preserved, however.</sup>

The reason for the `[IO.File]::WriteAllText()` approach not resulting in any newlines is different, as explained in Ansgar's answer.