# powershell output need in text file

Tags: powershell

```
$content=Get-ExcelImport "P:\Scripts\cord\cord.xlsx"
$content |

foreach 

{ if ($_ -ilike "*Rick*") {Write-Output $_}}
```

The output is coming out as the name is getting searched in the excel sheet and getting out as an output in powershell. I am not able to export the data in a text file. Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: What have you tried with regard to outputting to a text file? Have you done any research on how to write a text file from Powershell? This is a pretty common task and there are numerous blog posts & code examples.

Comment: I've tried to export the output in a text file but it's not happening, I am a beginner in powershell scripting. So stuck at this stage.

Comment: See `PowerShell` [Out-file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Alright let me try that

Comment: @RishabSaha show what you've attempted so that people can help you fix it. "it's not happening" does not provide enough information to help you (without writing it entirely for you).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link from a previous stack overflow question ( So this is a duplicate ?)

[Output ("echo") a variable to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122755/output-echo-a-variable-to-a-text-file)

> The simplest Hello World example...
>
> ```
> $hello = "Hello World"
> $hello | Out-File c:\debug.txt
> ```

Edit : Maybe you need more help on formating your data ?

Comment: To format the data in your variable before putting it in a text file, otherwise your question is a duplicate... as @vivek-kumar-singh and alroc mentionned you should try some research before posting here