# How do i use .txt input and output for math in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need to use a .txt as an input for a powershell command, and I need it to output to the same file in new row.
What kind of commands should i use?
I've only tried basic stuff such as

```
C:\"bunch O'shit"\input.txt *2   

"C:\"bunch O'shit"\input.txt" *2
```

Neither of which have worked.
Hlp plz.

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122755/output-echo-a-variable-to-a-text-file

Answer (score 0):

You need first to read the content of your file before you can start processing it. To read a file using PowerShell, you can use the `Get-Content`cmdlet.

Once you got the content of your file, you need to convert it to a type that you can use for doing calculations, i.e. you need to do a type-cast.

Type casting you can do like this, assuming the variable `$num` is a string:

```
[int]$num
```

this will create an integer out of a string.

You can check the type of a variable by using the `Get-Member`cmdlet.

Putting all this together:

```
# For the sake of it, let's create a file containing a single number
"2"  | Out-File -FilePath .\number.txt

# Let's read the file we just created and save the result in a variable
$num = Get-Content .\number.txt

# Do the type cast and multiply the result with another number
[int]$num * 2
```

You can at any point pipe the result to `Get-Member` and check what type it is.