# PowerShell : Set-Content Replace word and Encoding UTF8 without BOM

Tags: powershell, utf-8

I'd like to escape \ to \\ in csv file to upload to Redshift.
Following simple PowerShell script can replace $TargetWord \ to  $ReplaceWord \\ , as expected, but export utf-8 with bom and sometimes causes the Redshift copy error.

Any advice would be appreciated to improve it. Thank you in advance.

## Exp_Escape.ps1

```
Param(
    [string]$StrExpFile,
    [string]$TargetWord,
    [string]$ReplaceWord
)

# $(Get-Content "$StrExpFile").replace($TargetWord,$ReplaceWord) | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 "$StrExpFile"
```

Comment: The default encoding for set-content amounts to the same thing if there's no special characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- I**n [*PowerShell (Core) 7*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you get *BOM-less* UTF-8 files *by default***; `-Encoding utf8` and `-Encoding utf8NoBom` express that default explicitly; to excplicitly request a BOM, use `-Encoding utf8BOM`.
- **In *Windows PowerShell*, unfortunately, you must use a *workaround* to get BOM-less UTF-8**, because `-Encoding utf8` only produces UTF-8 files *with BOM* (and no other `utf8`-related values are supported).

The **workaround** requires **combining [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) with [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item)**, which (curiously) creates *BOM-less* UTF-8 files by default even in Windows PowerShell:

```bash
Param(
    [string]$StrExpFile,
    [string]$TargetWord,
    [string]$ReplaceWord
)

$null = 
  New-Item -Force $StrExpFile -Value (
    (Get-Content $StrExpFile).Replace($TargetWord, $ReplaceWord) | Out-String
  )
```

Note:

- `$null =`  is needed to discard the output object that `New-Item` emits (which is a file-info object describing the newly created file).
- `-Force` is needed in order to quietly overwrite an existing file by the same name (as [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) and [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) do by default).
- The `-Value` argument must be a *single (multi-line) string* to write to the file, which is what `Out-String` ensures.<sup>[1]</sup>

*Caveats*:

- For *non-string* input objects, `Out-String` creates the same rich for-display representations as `Out-File` and as you would see in the console by default.
- `New-Item` itself does *not* append a *trailing newline* when it writes the string to the file, but `Out-String` curiously does; while this happens to be handy here, it is generally problematic, as discussed in [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444).
- The alternative to using `Out-String` is to create the multi-line string *manually*, which is a bit more cumbersome (`` "`n" `` is used to create LF-only newlines, which PowerShell and most programs happily accept even on Windows; for platform-native newlines (CRLF) on Windows, use `[Environment]::NewLine` instead):

  ```bash
   $null = 
     New-Item -Force $StrExpFile -Value (
       ((Get-Content $StrExpFile).Replace($TargetWord, $ReplaceWord) -join "`n`") + "`n"
     )
  ```
- Since the entire file content must be passed as an *argument*,<sup>[2]</sup> it must fit into memory as a whole; the convenience function discussed next avoids this problem.

For a **convenience wrapper function around `Out-File`** for use in *Windows PowerShell*  that creates *BOM-less* UTF-8 files in streaming fashion, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969243/45375).

---

**Alternative**, with **direct use of .NET APIs**:

.NET APIs produce BOM-less UTF-8 files *by default*.
However, because .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's, *full* file paths must always be used, which requires more effort:

```bash
# In order for .NET API calls to work as expected,
# file paths must be expressed as *full, native* paths.
$OutDir = Split-Path -Parent $StrExpFile
if ($OutDir -eq '') { $OutDir = '.' }
$strExpFileFullPath = Join-Path (Convert-Path $OutDir) (Split-Path -Leaf $StrExpFile)

# Note: .NET APIs create BOM-less UTF-8 files *by default*
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines(
  $strExpFileFullPath,
  (Get-Content $StrExpFile).Replace($TargetWord, $ReplaceWord)
)
```

The above uses the [`System.IO.File.WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.WriteAllLines) method.

---

<sup>[1] Note that `Out-String` automatically *appends a trailing newline* to the string it outputs, which is actually desirable here (to ensure that the file ends with a newline, which `New-Item` itself doesn't do); however, in general this behavior is problematic, as discussed in [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444).</sup>

<sup>[2] Note that while `New-Item` technically supports receiving the content to write to the file via the *pipeline*, it unfortunately writes *each* to the target file *alone*, successively, with only the *last* one ending up in the file.</sup>