# How to avoid newline character from getting replaced with "?" in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace, character

I'm working on a config installer for a game. I want to make a menu for the user to choose from different colors for certain settings. To change those colors I use a PowerShell command in a batch file to find and replace the relevant text in a specific file. There is no problem with that alone.

In the replacement process, PowerShell also replaces the newline character found in the config file with a "?". That is not intended and I want to avoid that.

The character that gets replaced with a "?" is the following:

```
↵
```

I want to exclude that character from getting replaced in the process.

My code looks like that:

```
powershell -command "& {($p=gc "path.txt");(gc $p\GameConfig\SpecificFile.txt).replace('<col:Default>','<col:Green>') | sc $p\GameConfig\SpecificFile.txt}"
```

I have already tried to exclude the character like so:

```
powershell -command "& {($p=gc "path.txt");(gc $p\GameConfig\SpecificFile.txt).replace[↵]::escape('<col:Default>','<col:Green>') | sc $p\GameConfig\SpecificFile.txt}"
```

That didn't work.

I also tried to revert the replacement process of the newline character like so:

```
powershell -command "& {($p=gc "path.txt");(gc $p\GameConfig\SpecificFile.txt).replace('<col:Default>','<col:Green>') | sc $p\GameConfig\SpecificFile.txt}"
powershell -command "& {($p=gc "path.txt");(gc $p\GameConfig\SpecificFile.txt).replace('>?<','>↵<') | sc $p\GameConfig\SpecificFile.txt}"
```

That didn't work either.

I really need some help. Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: The font you are using doesn't support the character.  Change the font.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for your fast reply! I'm pretty new to PowerShell. I researched what font would support that character [https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22128/what-font-and-characters-are-used-for-the-line-break-symbol-used-in-microsoft] (Source). Cambria could be one of those fonts. The game itself uses a modified version of Helvetica though. How do I set the font to Cambria with a command? And how can I make sure that this font is installed on the computers of other users?

Comment: `sc -encoding utf8`

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Use the `-Encoding` parameter of [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) (whose built in alias is `sc` in Windows PowerShell) to specify a *Unicode* character encoding, to ensure that Unicode characters such as `↵` (DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH CORNER LEFTWARDS , [`U+21B5`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21b5)) are preserved; to use ***UTF-8* encoding**, for instance, add **`-Encoding utf8`**:

```
powershell -command "$p=gc path.txt; (gc -Encoding utf8 $p\GameConfig\SpecificFile.txt).Replace('<col:Default>','<col:Green>') | sc -Encoding utf8 $p\GameConfig\SpecificFile.txt"
```

A streamlined reformulation that speeds up processing by reading the file *as a whole* rather than *line by line*, using `Get-Content`'s `-Raw` switch as well as `Set-Content`'s `-NoNewLine` switch:

```
powershell -command "$p=(gc path.txt)+'\GameConfig\SpecificFile.txt'; (gc -Raw -Encoding utf8 $p).Replace('<col:Default>','<col:Green>') | sc -Encoding utf8 -NoNewLine $p"
```

To instead **use *UTF-16LE* ("Unicode") encoding**, use **`-Encoding Unicode`** (sic).

**Note**:

- In *Window PowerShell*, the legacy, ships-with-Windows Windows-only PowerShell edition you're using, this invariably creates a UTF-8 file *with a BOM*.

  - If that is undesired, you need a workaround - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375).
  - Note that if / once your input files are *BOM-less* UTF-8 files,  you also need to use `-Encoding utf8` for *reading* them properly with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) (whose built-in alias is `gc`), as used in the command above; without that, the file would be misinterpreted as ANSI-encoded in Windows PowerShell (see next point).
- By default, Windows PowerShell's `Set-Content` cmdlet uses ANSI encoding, i.e. the fixed-width 8-bit character encoding associated with your system's legacy system locale (aka language for non-Unicode programs), such as [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search/windows-1252) on US-English systems.

  - Trying to save a Unicode character such as `↵` that *cannot be represented in such an encoding* results in an (ASCII-range) `?` character getting saved instead, which is what you saw.
  - Note that the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition now fortunately consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF8.
- Generally, note that PowerShell's pipelines are *not* raw byte conduits: text file contents as well as output from external programs are invariably decoded into .NET strings before further processing, so that a `Get-Content ... | Set-Content ...` pipeline never preserves the original character encoding and instead uses *`Set-Content`*'s *default* encoding on writing (unless the `-Encoding` parameter is used); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for background information.

Comment: Including the BOM workaround my code looks like this now:

`powershell -command "& {($p=gc "path.txt");$null=new-item -force $p\Game\Config\SpecificFile.txt -value ((gc $p\Game\Config\SpecificFile.txt).replace('<col:Default>','<col:Green>') | out-string)}"`

And it works! Thank you very much.

Comment: I had some testers now and apparently there are some of them that get the `↵` replaced with `Ã¢â€<0xa0>Âµ`. I had them test both commands: `powershell -command "& {($p=gc "path.txt");(gc $p\Game\Config\SpecificFile.txt).replace('<col:Default>','<col:Green>') | sc -Encoding utf8 $p\Game\Config\SpecificFile.txt}"` and `powershell -command "& {($p=gc "path.txt");$null=new-item -force $p\Game\Config\SpecificFile.txt -value ((gc $p\Game\Config\SpecificFile.txt).replace('<col:Default>','<col:Green>') | out-string)}"`. Both commands caused that issue for them. Do you know a fix for that?

Comment: I tested more and noticed that the first sequence runs just fine and doesn't replace the `↵` character. I got 3 sequences to run though and after the 2nd one the `↵` gets replaced with `â†µ` and after the last sequence `â†µ` gets replaced with `Ã¢â€<0xa0>Âµ` . Is there a way to avoid that? I use your command with the BOM workaround for every sequence. @mklement0

Comment: @leiseg, use `gc -Encoding utf8` to ensure that the file are also _read_ as UTF-8. Once you have BOM-less UTF-8 files, Windows PowerShell will misinterpret them as ANSI-encoded.

Comment: Alright, that worked once again! Thank you a lot for your help and the explanations!

Comment: My pleasure, @leiseg. Note that the need for using `-Encoding utf8` with `gc` suggests that your files _originally_ were UTF-8 encoded _with_ a BOM (or used another Unicode encoding, such as UTF-16LE, which _always_ requires a BOM).

Comment: I already ran into that problem @mklement0. The `↵` is present in the file but in the game it shows the previous mentioned characters `â†µ`. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: @leiseg, it sounds like you may need the BOM after all, so re-save them with `sct -encoding utf8` and see if that helps.

Comment: If I try to implement `sct -encoding utf8` into my code, I get an error saying that `sct` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. Can you give me an example to implement that into my code? This is the code I'm using:
`powershell -command "& {($p=gc "path.txt");$null=new-item -force $p\Game\Config\SpecificFile.txt -value ((gc $p\Game\Config\SpecificFile.txt).replace('<col:Default>','<col:Green>') | out-string)}"` @mklement0

Comment: @leiseg, sorry, I meant `sc`, not `sct` (`sct` is my custom, cross-platform alias for `Set-Content`). Please see the updated command in my answer.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately that didn't work either @mklement0. I really want to use powershell for that but if there's no other way I will use some third party find text and replace tool.

Comment: @leiseg, PowerShell can definitely get you there, but you need to be clear on the requirements: (a) What specific character encoding does your _original_ `...\Game\Config\SpecificFile.txt` file use? If it isn't property decoded by `Get-Content` _by default_, you must pass an `-Encoding` argument. (b) To _preserve_ that encoding after performing your string replacement and on re-saving the file, you must use pass the _same_ `-Encoding` argument to `Set-Content` (`sc`) - _except_ if the encoding is _BOM-less_ UTF-8, in which case you need the `New-Item` workaround (in Windows PowerShell).

Comment: Alright, I found out that the original file is encoded as UTF16LE. If I use the commands you provided, it get's encoded as UTF8. UTF8 is needed to save the `↵` character though. Is there a way to encode the file as UTF16LE again? @mklement0

Comment: @leiseg, yes, use `-Encoding Unicode`

Comment: This finally works! Thanks for the third time now. My problem is solved! @mklement0