# Read TXT file, replace values and save file

Tags: powershell

Mutiple txt files containg values that needs to be changed

Starting (#Start=) hour and stop (#Stop=) hour and day needs to be updated and saved

The txt file contains different dates so no generic -replace can be used

```
    $files = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\swsetup\Readings\" -Filter "*.txt"
    Foreach ($file in $files) {
        $result= get-content $file.fullname | %{$_ -match "//1"}
    
        if ($result-contains $true) {
            Write-Host "match - Do nothing!"
        } else {
            Write-Host "No match, cont..."
    
            $ValuesStart = Select-String -path $file.fullname -Pattern "#Start="
            $valuesStart
    
            # Dynamic response, need to handle all $values
            $valueStart[0]
        }
    }
```

Above code results in:

```
Result = PS C:\SWSetup> $valuesStart

Readings\file.txt:15:#Start=2023-11-01.01:00:00
Readings\file.txt:51:#Start=2023-11-01.01:00:00
```

this TXT file contains two (2) entries with start (and stop)

```
Readings\\file.txt:16:#Stop=2023-11-02.00:00:00
Readings\\file.txt:52:#Stop=2023-11-02.00:00:00
```

````

Question:

How to change the #Start= to 00:00:00 and the #Stop= to 2023-11-01-23:00:00 and save the file again as a new txt file. The date (day) value needs to be same for start and stop

**To break it down:**

How to extract the date values,

- from each line (result), use the "day" for Stop= value

How to save the modified line (data)

br

erik

(similiar post created, will remove it)

Format of TXT file

```
##Start-message
 #Id=TTIM02 2023-11-02.08:33:44
 #Message-type=Settlement-data
 #Version=1.2
 #From=TTIM02
 #To=MDMS
 #Time=2023-11-02.08:33:44
 #Reference-table=TTIM02
 #GMT-reference=+1
 #Number-of-objects=2
 #Description=Meter hourly values from TTIM02

##Time-series
#Reference=12
#Start=2023-11-01.01:00:00
#Stop=2023-11-02.00:00:00
#Step=0000-00-00.01:00:00
#Unit=kWh
#Value=<
0.224//0
0.175//0
0.257//0
0.178//0
0.2//0
0.247//0
0.066//0
0.071//0
0.057//0
0.037//0
0.074//0
0.037//0
0.265//0
1.613//0
0.656//0
0.355//0
0.22//0
0.219//0
0.275//0
0.25//0
0.625//0
1.88//0
0.346//0
0.375//0
>
  #No-of-values=24
  #Sum=8.702
  #Installation=12-3

##Time-series
#Reference=123
#Start=2023-11-01.01:00:00
#Stop=2023-11-02.00:00:00
#Step=0000-00-00.01:00:00
#Unit=kWh
#Value=<
0.029//0
0.027//0
0.027//0
0.026//0
0.026//0
0.024//0
0.028//0
0.038//0
0.038//0
0.028//0
0.025//0
0.023//0
0.023//0
0.023//0
0.023//0
0.026//0
0.026//0
0.025//0
0.025//0
0.03//0
0.025//0
0.031//0
0.028//0
0.024//0
>
  #No-of-values=24
  #Sum=0.648
  #Installation=123-3

##End-message
 #Number-of-objects=2
 #Id=TTIM02 2023-11-02.08:33:44
```

Comment: I'm quite unsure what your question is. The most straight forward apporach would be to use a `-replace` with the proper regex pattern. ‍♂️ At the moment you're just searching for `"//1"` in your code.  

Comment: thx for the reply. 
Replace might work, but I need to know what to replace with.  The dates will differ, I need to be able to read the #Start= and use that for the #Stop=
- as I hope the code example shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with the `-File` and `-Regex` parameters for line-by-line processing of text files with [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based matching:

```bash
Get-ChildItem C:\swsetup\Readings -Filter *.txt |
  ForEach-Object {
    $modifiedLines =
      switch -Regex -File $_.FullName {
        '(^#Start=)([^.]+)' {
          $date = $Matches.2
          $Matches.1 + $date + '.00:00:00' # Output modified line.
          continue
        }
        '^#Stop=' {
          $Matches.0 + $date + '.23:00:00' # Output modified line.
          continue
        }
        default { $_ } # Other lines: pass them through.
      }
    # Uncomment this to save the modified lines back to the input file.
    # $_ | Set-Content -Value $modifiedLines -WhatIf 
    # DIAGNOSTIC OUTPUT:
    $modifiedLines
    Write-Host "-------- Above is the modified content of: $($_.FullName)"
    pause
  }
```

Note:

- As when using the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), the results of a successful regex match are stored in the **[automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches)**, which can be accessed in the action script block associated with the successfully matched branch-condition regex, as shown above.
- **Character encoding** caveats:

  - On *input*, `switch -File` *invariably* interprets files *without a BOM* as *UTF-8*-encoded, even in *Windows PowerShell*.

    - You'd need a different approach if you need to specify a different encoding; an efficient alternative is to use a [`[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.ReadLines)`] .NET API call - see below.
  - On *output*, you may have to use an `-Encoding` argument with [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content), because an input file's specific character encoding is never preserved in the PowerShell pipeline (the content is invariably decoded into .NET strings without storing information about the original encoding).

    - On saving (back) to a file, it is the chosen cmdlet's / redirection operator's *default* encoding that is applied.
    - Unfortunately, the defaults differ by cmdlet in *Windows PowerShell* (notably, ANSI for `Set-Content` and UTF-16LE ("Unicode") for `Out-File` / `>`), whereas *PowerShell (Core) 7+* now sensibly defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8.
    - If you want to create UTF-8 files *without a BOM* in *Windows PowerShell*, `Set-Content` won't work, and you'll need the workaround based on `New-Item` described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375) and as shown below.

---

##### Variant with explicit character-encoding control:

This example:

- Controls the input character encoding via a [`[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.ReadLines) .NET API call to which a [`System.Text.Encoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.Encoding) instance is passed.
- Creates BOM-less UTF-8 output files, even in *Windows PowerShell* (in PowerShell (Core) 7+, you could just use `Set-Content`).

```bash
Get-ChildItem C:\swsetup\Readings -Filter *.txt |
  ForEach-Object {
    $modifiedLines =
      switch -Regex (
        # SPECIFY THE INPUT ENCODING HERE. Always use a FULL PATH in .NET calls.
        [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(
          $_.FullName,
          [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
        )
      ) {
        '(^#Start=)([^.]+)' {
          $date = $Matches.2
          $Matches.1 + $date + '.00:00:00' # Output modified line.
        }
        '^#Stop=' {
          $Matches.0 + $date + '.23:00:00' # Output modified line.
        }
        default { $_ } # Other lines: pass them through.
      }
    # Create a BOM-less UTF-8 output file, even in Windows PowerShell.
    # (In PowerShell 7+, you can use Set-Content, as usual.)
    # For a different encoding, use Set-Content -Encoding.
    # -WhatIf PREVIEWS the operation; remove it to create actual files.
    New-Item -WhatIf -Force $_.FullName -Value (($modifiedLines -join [Environment]::NewLine) + [Environment]::NewLine) | Out-Null
  }
```

Comment: thx for the reply !!, works perfectly  (first variant), I have no idea how :)

Question
Is it also possible in the same "$modifiedLines section" to also switch places between:

#Reference=
#Installation=

If not I will copy your exellent code and run it again replacing the start and stop, but I assume there is a more elegant way ....

Comment: Glad to hear it, @erwe. You mean reordering lines? That would require more work. If you get stuck trying to implement it yourself, I encourage you to ask a new question.

Comment: Not really reordering, more switch values between the two:

Value from #Reference = >  #Installation and viceversa

Comment: @erwe: Inserting a new branch should work: `'^#Reference(=.*)$' { '#Installation' + $Matches.1; continue }`

Comment: switch -Regex -File $_.FullName {
        '(^#Start=)([^.]+)' {
          $date = $Matches.2
          $Matches.1 + $date + '.00:00:00' # Output modified line.
        }
        '^#Stop=' {
          $Matches.0 + $date + '.23:00:00' # Output modified line.
        }
        '^#Reference(=.*)$' {
         '#Installation' + $Matches.1; continue
         }
        default { $_ } # Other lines: pass them through.

Comment: like that ?, it do switches the values but the "#Reference=" part is also renamed to "installation"

Comment: @erwe: I thought renaming `#Reference` to `#Installation` is what you wanted - that is all my suggestion does. I'm unclear on you real intent. Are you saying you want to take the value from the `#Installation` line and replace the existing _value_ in the `#Reference` line? That would take  quite a bit more work.