# Problem with Unicode characters when backing up and restoring mysql database in docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, powershell

I used this code to create a database in docker:

```
docker run -d -p 9906:3306 --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234567890 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb -e MYSQL_USER=myuser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=123 mysql --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_persian_ci;
```

When I tried to backup and restore using PhpMyAdmin, everything is fine. But when I tried to use docker commands in PowerShell, process is done but Unicode characters is disturbed like:

> '+«+¿+¦ +¬+¡+ä¦î+ä¦î +º+ê+ä'

instead of:

> 'خبر تحلیلی اول'

Here is my backup and restore commands:

```
# Backup:
docker exec db /usr/bin/mysqldump -u myuser --password=123 --no-tablespaces mydb | set-content backup__.sql;

# Restore:
get-content backup.sql | docker exec -i db mysql -u myuser --password=123 mydb;
```

**EDIT**

In fact, I want to deliver a .ps1 file to the product manager to backup and restore database without logging into phpMyAdmin. Have you got another suggestion except PS if PS is the problem?

Comment: Thanks. Maybe. in fact, I want to deliver a .ps1 file to the product manager to backup and restore database without logging into phpMyAdmin. Have you got another suggestion except PS?

Comment: `Set-Content` will definitely apply some [encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.4#-encoding). Better pipe it inside your container to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To make the current PowerShell console fully support UTF-8 - which only matters when PowerShell communicates *with external programs* such as `docker` - you need to set `[Console]::InputEncoding` and `[Console]::OutputEncoding` as well as PowerShell's [`$OutputEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding) preference variable to UTF-8 (in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the latter - only - already defaults to that).
- To make [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) use UTF-8 when saving a file, pass it `-Encoding utf8`.

  - The caveat is that in *Windows PowerShell* you'll invariably get a UTF-8 file *with a BOM*.

    - If needed (not here), there a workarounds for creating BOM-less UTF-8 files, such as via `New-Item` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375).
  - However, this doesn't matter in  your case, because you're using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) to read the file, which handles a BOM correctly (and, in fact, *needs* in order for the decoding to be recognized in *Windows PowerShell*).
    In *PowerShell 7+*, *BOM-less UTF-8* is the consistent default for *PowerShell* commands, so you don't need `-Encoding utf8` (which effectively requests what the default behavior is anyway; to get a BOM there, you'd need `-Encoding utf8bom`) and `Get-Content` now assumes UTF-8 in the absence of a BOM (whereas in *Windows PowerShell* it assumes the active legacy *ANSI* code page).

Therefore:

```bash
# Switch PowerShell and the console to UTF-8.
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = 
  [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

# Backup:
# Note the uses of -Encoding uf8
docker exec db /usr/bin/mysqldump -u myuser --password=123 --no-tablespaces mydb |
  set-content -Encoding utf8 backup__.sql

# Restore:
get-content backup.sql | 
  docker exec -i db mysql -u myuser --password=123 mydb;
```

Note:

- The above assumes that `docker exec db /usr/bin/mysqldump ...` emits UTF-8 encoded text and similarly expects it via the pipeline (stdin); replace `[System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()` with the actual encoding if it differs.
- `[Console]::InputEncoding` and `[Console]::OutputEncoding` effectively set the input and output *code pages* for the current console, as then reflected in the output from `chcp` (note, however that you cannot `chcp` to *set* the active code pages from inside PowerShell, because .NET caches the original ones):

  - Strictly speaking, `[Console]::InputEncoding` doesn't come into play from inside a PowerShell session, but `[Console]::OutputEncoding` is what PowerShell uses to decode stdout output *from* an external program.
  - Conversely, `$OutputEncoding` is the encoding PowerShell uses when sending data *to* an external program (which the latter reads via its stdin stream).
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) discusses how you can make your PowerShell console *default* to UTF-8, including a Windows 10+ method for configuring a system to use UTF-8 *system-wide*, in which case both the OEM and the ANSI code page are set to `65001` (UTF-8). However, the latter has *far-reaching consequences* in that it can change the behavior of existing console applications and PowerShell scripts.

Comment: Glad to see that it helped, @MortezaM; my pleasure.