# Line 1: unknown keyword ' file' ffmpeg

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, character-encoding

I am trying to run a concation of multiple files using ffmpeg. Followed directions in docs and getting

```
Line 1: unknown keyword 'file'
[in#0 @ 000001b09b25e840] Error opening input: Invalid data found when processing input
Error opening input file mylist.txt.
Error opening input files: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. The [text file](https://pastebin.com/gBcMGXFF) appears to be in the correct format.

```
$clips = Get-ChildItem -Path Y:\****\Test -File -Filter "*.mp4"
$regex = "(?:\w+)-(?:[i]+-)?(?<scene_id>\d+)-(?<clip_id>\d+)-(?:\w+)"
$groupedScenes = $clips | Group-Object {[regex]::Match($_.Name, $regex).Groups["scene_id"].value}
foreach($scene in $groupedScenes)
{
    $sortedScene = $scene.Group | Sort-Object {[regex]::Match($_.Name, $regex).Groups["clip_id"].value -as [int]} 
    foreach($i in $sortedScene) 
    {
        "file 'Y:\*****\Test\$i'" | Out-File mylist.txt -Encoding utf8 -Append
    }
    .\ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -map 0 -c:v hevc_amf -quality quality -rc cqp -qp_p 26 -qp_i 26 -c:a aac -b:a 128K -y Y:\*****\Test\Procssed\$sortedScene.mp4
    Remove-Item mylist.txt
}
```

Comment: Please share the file causing the problems.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gBcMGXFF I have also copied the file path into windows explorer to ensure i had a correct path

Comment: That info belongs in your question. Click [edit] and add the first 3-4 lines. Try replacing the backslashes with forward slashes - only Windows uses backslashes.

Comment: Try add-content instead of out-file.  Out-file is a bit weird with encodings while appending.  I don't know ffmpeg errors.

Answer (score 3):

The following was verified with version 6.1 of `ffmpeg`:

- The character encoding of a **file passed to the `-i` option** must be ***BOM-less* UTF-8**.
- Alternatively, you may use **ASCII** encoding, but ***only if* your file paths contain *ASCII-range characters only***, given that ASCII encoding is a *subset* of BOM-less UTF-8 encoding.

  - To put it differently: an ASCII-encoded file is by definition also a BOM-less UTF-8 file - just one that happens to contain ASCII characters only.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

It follows that **UTF-8 files *with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)* are *not* accepted**:

- In *Windows PowerShell*, `-Encoding utf8` *invariably* creates UTF-8 files *with BOM*, and `ffmpeg` then misinterpreted the BOM *as part of the file's content*, breaking the recognition of the first `file` keyword - this is what you ran into:

  - Specifically, the BOM is interpreted as the ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE, [`U+FEFF`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff) Unicode character (which it technically is); this character typically has *no* printable representation - such as in a browser, which is why the error message in your question seemingly complains about the - correct - `file` keyword; in a *console window* on Windows, however, the character renders *like a space*, making the problem more obvious:

    ```bash
    Line 1: unknown keyword ' file'
    ```
- By contrast, in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) it creates UTF-8 files *without* a BOM, both with `-Encoding utf8` and *by default* (conversely, you need `-Encoding utf8BOM` to create files *with* a BOM).

Therefore:

- In ***PowerShell (Core) 7+***, your code **should work as-is**, and you can even omit the
  `-Encoding utf8` argument.
- In ***Windows PowerShell*** you need one of two **workarounds**:

  - If your file paths are composed exclusively of ASCII-range characters, use `-Encoding Ascii` rather than `-Encoding utf8` in your `Out-File` call.
  - Otherwise, use [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) to create your file, which - surprisingly - (invariably) creates BOM-*less* UTF-8 files, even in Windows PowerShell:

    ```bash
    $null = 
      New-Item -Force mylist.txt -Value (
        $sortedScene | 
          ForEach-Object { "file 'Y:\*****\Test\$_'" } |
          Out-String
      )
    ```

    - For more information about this workaround, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375).

---

<sup>[1] ASCII characters form the *7-bit subrange* of [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), i.e. characters with code points between [`U+0000`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0) an [`U+007F`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7f), which in the context of UTF-8/ASCII encoding are encoded as *single bytes* with values between `0x0` and `0x7F` (`127`).

Any other characters (a) cannot be represented in ASCII at all (encoders may throw an error or use a *replacement character* when encountering such characters, such as a verbatim `?`) and (b) require a *multi-byte* representation in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (between 2 and 4 bytes).</sup>