# Replace multilines file every time a certain string occurs in another file with powershell

Tags: powershell, replace, line

Replace multilines file every time a certain string occurs in another file with powershell.

I have a file with about 50 thousand different lines of text that needs to be placed into another file (with 500 thousand lines) every time this string occurs:

```
     [2]
      1 string data = "
```

This string is followed by an English text and ends with **"** and must be replaced with an Italian text that I take from the 50 thousand line file.

Example
File of 500 thousand lines (**code.txt**):

```
    [0]
     1 string data = ""
    [1]
     1 string data = "first spanish text"
    [2]
     1 string data = "first english text"
    [0]
     1 string data = ""
    [1]
     1 string data = "another text in spanish"
    [2]
     1 string data = "here is another text in English"
```

File of 50 thousand lines (**ita.txt**):

```
first text in Italian
another text in Italian
one again
```

Merged Output (**codeita.txt**):

```
    [0]
     1 string data = ""
    [1]
     1 string data = "first spanish text"
    [2]
     1 string data = "first text in Italian"
    [0]
     1 string data = ""
    [1]
     1 string data = "another text in spanish"
    [2]
     1 string data = "another text in Italian"
```

Code that I tried to use without success:

```
cut -s -d = -f 1 code.txt > part1.txt
cut -s -d = -f 2 code.txt > part2en.txt
paste -d = part1.txt ita.txt > codeita.txt
```

Comment: **Hey** _(the emboldening is deliberate)_, please read the comments from [your first attempt at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77891508/). Then your [second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77891997). Now ask yourself, "am I doing myself any favors here?". Your question is still off topic.

Comment: @Compo: While it is always preferable to show one's own efforts, a well-thought-out question that doesn't have a trivial, answered-before solution can be valuable even without that or with effort that is far from a feasible solution, as in this case. To me, the question is well-defined and represents a problem that could be of general interest.

Comment: That's exactly the same question you already asked twice!!!

Comment: @Olaf, I hadn't followed the history and while it is obviously not proper to repost a question as-is after it has been closed and then self-deleted,
the other questions are now gone, and I believe the question _is_ on-topic and worth answering, for the reasons stated in my previous comment. 
Others may (again) disagree, and should this question too get closed and should the re-posting pattern continue, a flag can be raised.
I suggest cutting a new contributor some slack and I suggest basing votes solely on the intrinsic merits of a question.

Comment: Well ... I strongly disagree this time but you already answered anyway .... ‍♂️

Comment: I disagree too @mklement0. IMO your comment is biased to your own intent on providing an answer, not to the validity of what was asked, how it was posed, the lack of any reasonable attempt at the code, understanding the comments, or willingness to remain within the remit of this site's guidance. _Also, your use of the term 'contributor' suggests that the OP has in some way helped other site readers, when I doubt that is actually true in this case_.

Comment: @Compo: We'll have to agree to disagree that _insufficient_ effort (or even absence thereof) _per se_ makes a question off-topic - to me, this attitude does future readers a disservice, as they won't care _who_ put in the effort, as long as they see a well-defined, focused problem accompanied by a focused solution. The procedural missteps by the OP are a separate matter, and can be resolved as suggested.

Comment: @Compo: _New contributor_ is the label given by the site to newcomers, and asking  a question is by definition a contribution. My point is: a well-defined problem of potentially general interest _alone_ can be a _valuable_ contribution, as it allows for similarly focused solutions to be posted, which future readers with similar problems will benefit from (too). It is valid to disagree whether the question at hand falls into this category - to me it does, and that's why I chose to answer - but I don't think questions should be dismissed _solely_ for (perceived) insufficient self-solving effort.

Comment: Had you taken time to read the previous incarnations, the OP was looking for a solution using NotePad++, a batch file, or PowerShell. In the time between Mofi commenting about the inadequacies of batch files, they could not have realistically researched or properly attempted the task in PowerShell or NotePad++. They were looking only for someone to do that for them in one or more of those methods, not for assistance with programming code. There was no debugging or research information provided along side their attempt, or any description of how that failed to perform as intended or expected.

Comment: @Compo: What happened prior to this discussion is _irrelevant_ to the points that I've made. Separately, the following actions are _inappropriate_: (a) Condescending to others ("had you taken time") and (b) wanting to punish posters for their perceived moral failings. None of this is to take away from the fact that the _OP could and arguably should have done more_ to solve their own problem - it just doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Also, Kenryoku's own solution attempt based on the `cut` and `paste` Unix utilities -  the absence of a description of the _symptoms_ of falling short notwithstanding - arguably _is_ an earnest attempt to solve the problem. I've updated my answer to explain in what way, specifically, it falls short.

Comment: @mklement0, regarding 'the following actions are inappropriate: (a) Condescending to others ("had you taken time")', I was merely responding to your own admission, '@Olaf, I hadn't followed the history', i.e. a fact, with absolutely no undertone that I held some form of superiority over you. In fact it feels more like you are trying to exert your superior site reputation over myself for having a differing opinion, in this case. You began by stating that we would "agree to disagree", then publicly pursued me for those disagreements. Am I expected/supposed to not respond to those?

Comment: @Compo: I misspoke: We shouldn't agree to disagree _yet_. You should engage the arguments that I've made _first_ and only if we don't reach a _shared understanding_ should we agree to disagree. Glad to hear you didn't mean to condescend. Please disregard this part of my argument. The other points stand. As for the "superior site reputation" part: I can only assure you in good faith that this never factors into my comments - nor should it ever: it is inherently at odds with an earnest quest for the (best approximation of) truth.

Comment: You clearly wish to have the final word on this @mklement0, so, as my reputation superior, I hereby forfeit any attempt to take that accolade.

Comment: @Compo: What I'll take away from this: You didn't hear me (and, yes, I'm aware of the irony of my posting yet another comment).

Comment: Sorry, because of my fault a debate was created, it was not my intention.

Comment: No worries, @Kenryoku: it's a debate worth having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your `cut` and `paste`-based attempt isn't sophisticated enough to get the transformation you need:

  - Your [`cut`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) commands effectively *omit* lines from the input files, which cannot achieve the desired output format.

    - The reason is your use of the `-s` option, which *suppresses* (omits) lines that do not contain the specified delimiter (`-d`), `=`.
      However, even *not* specifying `-s` wouldn't help - see next point.
  - Your [`paste`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html) command (a) doesn't perform *conditional* merging (only lines preceded by a `[2]` line must be targeted) and (b) lacks the required `"..."` enclosure around the values pasted from `ita.txt`
- One option is to use [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based string replacements, as demonstrated below.

  - For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/VejySo/4); note that matching could be made more stringent, but the concise form below should work with your files.

```bash
# Create a reader for file ita.txt that 
# allows line-by-line reading on demand.
$reader = [IO.StreamReader] (Convert-Path ita.txt)

# Read code.txt as a whole
# and perform regex-based replacements of the parts
# of interest, iteratively using ita.txt's lines as replacement text.
[regex]::Replace(
  (Get-Content -Raw -Encoding utf8 code.txt),
  '(?<=\[2\][^=]+?= ").*(?=")',
  { $reader.ReadLine() }
) | 
  Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding utf8 codeita.txt  # Save to the output file.

$reader.Dispose() # Close and dispose of the reader.
```

See also:

- The [`System.IO.StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamReader) .NET class.

  - Note that the input path is passed via the [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) cmdlet, so as to ensure that a *full path* is passed, which is necessary because .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's.
- The [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace) method.

  - Note that in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) you could use PowerShell's [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator instead:

    ```bash
    (Get-Content -Raw -Encoding utf8 code.txt) `
      -replace '(?<=\[2\][^=]+?= ").*(?=")', { $reader.ReadLine() }
    ```
  - Note: As PowerShell generally is, `-replace` is case-*insensitive* by default, but that doesn't make a difference here (use the `-creplace` variant for case-sensitivity, and, conversely, pass `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase` as an additional argument to `[regex]::Replace()` to make it case-insensitive).
- The [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) cmdlets for reading and writing text files.

  - Note the use of `-Encoding utf8` to ensure that *Windows PowerShell* properly reads your text file as UTF-8-encoded and also outputs it as such (PowerShell 7+ does this by default).<sup>[1]</sup>
  - By contrast, .NET APIs *always* default to (BOM-less) UTF-8, both in the legacy, Windows-only .NET Framework edition (which underlies *Windows PowerShell*) as well as in the modern, cross-platform .NET (Core) edition (which underlies PowerShell 7+).

---

<sup>[1] Note that in *Windows PowerShell* this creates UTF-8 files *with a BOM*. If this is a problem, see the workarounds in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375).</sup>

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I am grateful. Unfortunately, I have two problems:
1 it does not paste all the strings correctly, because in the files there are strings with double " at the start and at the end (1 string data = ""some text"") and when they occur, they are skipped, leaving the English text in place and bringing the text that was supposed to be there to the next line.
2 Characters are encoded incorrectly, making accented letters, Japanese, Korean, etc. illegible.

Comment: @Kenryoku: Please see my update, which hopefully addresses both your problems (the regex and regex101.com links were updated too). On a meta note: Please seek resolution _via comments_ first, before updating your _question_ in a manner that may cause confusion in future readers - I've reverted your question to an earlier form.

Comment: sorry, I am new here, next time I will read if there were any changes before commenting.
It still doesn't work, I'm trying to figure out why and how to modify the regex.
One error I noticed is that it ends some Italian text on this string type: 1 string Term = " instead it should not...
As for utf8, it fixed the accents but not the Asian characters, with -Encoding UT8-BOM, my powershell tells me it doesn't consider it.
Thank you for your patience

Comment: @Kenryoku, I neglected to add `-Encoding utf8` to `Set-Content` too (fixed now) in oder to ensure UTF-8 _output too_, but note that in _Windows PowerShell_ this invariably creates UTF-8 files _with a BOM_ (if you must avoid that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375)). As for the problem with some Italian texts: I have no explanation, and the problem doesn't occur with your sample data. To get help with this problem, please create a _new_ question post that references this post and focuses _only_ on this remaining problem, ideally in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: @Kenryoku, I've posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77893476/45375) to [your follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77893406/45375), and I've also updated this answer to include the same improvement.