# Select all lines starting with a given string and ending with " with Regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to translate certain lines of a code from English into Italian.
I have solved almost everything thanks to mklement0 who helped me with this post:

[Replace multilines file every time a certain string occurs in another file with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77892422/replace-multilines-file-every-time-a-certain-string-occurs-in-another-file-with)

However, the Regex code does not match the result I want.

Using Regex I would like to select all the contents between two " of all the lines that begin with this string:

```
[2]
     1 string data = "
```

I tried the following code:

```
(?<=\[2\][^=]+? 1 string data = ")[^"]+
```

But the problem is that if other " occur within the sentence, it does not select the whole sentence up to the last ", but the whole sentence up to the first " and with $ I could not solve it.

Example:

```
[2]
     1 string data = ""some text" in english" and "other""
```

Must become:

```
[2]
     1 string data = ""un pò di testo" in Italiano" e "altro""
```

Not:

```
[2]
     1 string data = "some text".
```

Comment: What needs to be replaced?  Is it everything between the first double quote `"` to the last double quote `"` on the line?  In your example, is it `"some text" in english" and "other"` that needs to be replaced?

Comment: yes, just like that, this part is correct: (?<==[2\][^=]+? 1 string data = ') the error lies in this: [^"]+

Comment: The background of the question (like how is the file created or where -in which programming language- is it used?), might help to find an actual parser which is usually the correct way to go and might prevent pitfalls as described here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex just needs a slight tweak (note the use of `.*(?=")` instead of `[^"]+`; as in the linked answer, the `1 string data` part isn't spelled out):

- Use `'(?<=\[2\][^=]+?= ").*(?=")'` to ensure that everything up to the *last* `"` on the line containing the `"..."` string following the  `=` is replaced, including when there's *no text* between the first and last `"` (i.e., `... = ""`)

To demonstrate with a `-replace` operation using a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`) as its input:

```bash
@'
[2]
     1 string data = ""some text" in english" and "other""
'@ -replace '(?<=\[2\][^=]+?= ").*(?=")', 
            '"un pò di testo" in Italiano" e "altro"'
```

Output:

```bash
[2]
     1 string data = ""un pò di testo" in Italiano" e "altro""
```

- For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/VejySo/4).
- I've also updated [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77892660/45375) to include this improvement.

Comment: Is perfect if it were not for a specific problem that occurs in my text, when in the English text between the "" there is nothing, but in the Italian text there is, the Italian text goes directly into the next line, ruining the whole file D:

Comment: @Kenryoku: Please see my update (just replace `.+(?=")` with `.*(?=")`)

Comment: Grazie mille! Non sai quanto ti sono riconoscente, grazie a te non ho perso del tempo inutilmente, grazie ancora.

Comment: Sono felice che le risposte abbiano aiutato, @Kenryoku. Piacere mio. (Disclaimer: translation courtesy of Google Translate)

Comment: Sorry, I wrote you in italian by mistake

Comment: @Kenryoku :) No worries.As long as the technically relevant parts are in English, all is good. (Conversational comments such as these may eventually get removed anyway).