# Get 3rd column and put it in another file for all CSV files with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, cut

I have a folder, with subfolders full of csv files.
For each file I would like to get only the third column and save it in another file.

Example:

filedata1.csv

```
aa,bb,cc
cat,horse,"dog, bird"
4th,33,first and second
```

filedata1column3.csv

```
cc
dog, bird
first and second
```

what I tried but it turns out wrong:

```
param ( [String] $Filename  = '*.csv',
            [String] $SourceDir = 'C:\Data\',
    )
    
ForEach ($csvFile in Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Filter $Filename){
            (Import-Csv $csvFile)
            cut -d, -f 3 *.csv > *column3.csv
```

Comment: The sample input file has `cc` as the 3rd column header, but in the output example the column header says `bb` - which is it?

Comment: my mistake when edit it, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views) to determine each file's column names from the objects that [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) parses the CSV data into, and extract the third name.
- Then use [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to extract all property values from the rows (objects), relying on PowerShell's ability to use *expressions* (variable references) as property names.
- Use [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) in conjunction with `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f) to determine a suitable output file path and name, based on the input file name.

```bash
# ... parameter declaration and foreach loop omitted.
# The following is what needs to go *inside the foreach loop*.

# Import all rows.
$rows = Import-Csv $csvFile
# Determine the name of the third column
$thirdColName = ($rows[0].psobject.Properties.Name)[2]

# Determine a suitable output file path and name.
# Here, the output file is placed in the same directory as the input file, 
# with '_colummn3' appended to the latter's base name.
$outFile =
  Join-Path $csvFile.DirectoryName ('{0}_column3.csv' -f $csvFile.BaseName)

# Output the header column
$thirdColName > $outFile
# Append the values of the third column
$rows.$thirdColName >> $outFile
```

Note:

- In *Windows* PowerShell, `>` and `>>` create "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) files, whereas in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) they create BOM-less UTF-8 files.
- If you need a different encoding, use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) and [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) with an `-Encoding` argument, but note that in Windows PowerShell you cannot create *BOM-less* UTF-8 files that way.

  - If you do need BOM-less UTF-8 files in Windows PowerShell, use the workaround from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375) (use this *instead* of the `>` and `>>` statements, and use `` "`r`n" `` instead of `` "`n" `` if you need Windows-format CRLF newlines):

    ```bash
    # Write the entire file as BOM-less UTF-8.
    $null =
      New-Item -Force $outFile -Value (
        $thirdColName + "`n" + ($rows.$thirdColName -join "`n") + "`n"
      )
    ```

---

To **put it all together** in a solution that:

- parameterizes the inputs further while providing default values
- creates BOM-less UTF-8 files.

Place the code in a `.ps1` file and invoke the latter (e.g. `./Script.ps1`), optionally with arguments that override the defaults.

```bash
param(
  $FileName = '*.csv', # File-name filter
  $SourceDir = $PWD,   # Input-files dir., default to current
  $OutDir = $PWD,      # Output-files dir., default to current
  $ColumnIndex = 3,    # 1-based index of the col. of interest
  # Suffix to append to the input file name's base name 
  # to form the output file name.
  $OutFileBaseNameSuffix = "_column$ColumnIndex"
)

foreach ($csvFile in Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Filter $Filename) {

  # If the output files are written to the same dir. as the input files,
  # exclude any output files from a previous run.
  if ($SourceDir -eq $OutDir -and $csvFile.BaseName -like "*$OutFileBaseNameSuffix") { continue }

  # Import all rows for the file at hand.
  $rows = Import-Csv $csvFile
  # Determine the name of the column with the index of interest.
  # Subtract -1 from $ColumnIndex, because array indices are *0*-based.
  $colName = ($rows[0].psobject.Properties.Name)[$ColumnIndex-1]

  # Determine the output file path and name.
  $outFile =
    Join-Path $OutDir ('{0}{1}.csv' -f $csvFile.BaseName, $OutFileBaseNameSuffix)

  # Write the entire file, as BOM-less UTF-8.
  $null =
    New-Item -Force $outFile -Value (
      $colName + "`n" + ($rows.$colName -join "`n") + "`n"
    )

}
```

Comment: There might be several .csv files that have the same name for the third column. Should this `Test-Path` to see if the file exists and only append?

Comment: yes, I would need utf8 encoding and I have a powershell version 5, I'll see if I can fix it according to your guidelines

Comment: @lit, the output file is placed in the same directory as the input file, and appends `_column3` to the latter's base name, so there should be no naming conflicts.

Comment: @EdoardoEndrizzi, I've spelled out the workaround for Windows PowerShell in an update to the answer.

Comment: so $rows.$thirdColName >> $outFile became $null =
  New-Item -Force $outFile -Value (
    $thirdColName + "`n" + ($rows.$thirdColName -join "`n") + "`n"
  ) sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: @EdoardoEndrizzi: Use _only_ the `New-Item` call, as shown: it _replaces_ the lines that contain `>` and `>>` in the first code snippet.

Comment: so do I add it at the end? then one last question, if my text is full of \n but I want it not go in a new line when it occurs, should I use "`r`n" instead of "`n"?

Comment: @EdoardoEndrizzi, yes, you replace all lines in the first snippet that start with `# Output the header column` with the second snippet. If your text contains _literal_ `\n` sequences, you'd have to replace those with actual newlines. These days it's usually fine to just use `"\`n"` (LF-only) newlines even on Windows.

Comment: So do I need to specify a path? because I would have liked it to work on the folder in which powershell was executed, but it gives me an error due to an empty path

Comment: @EdoardoEndrizzi, you still need your parameter declaration and your `foreach` loop. For brevity, this answer only shows what needs to go _inside that loop_. If you want the output files to be placed in the _current directory_ rather than alongside the input files, replace `$csvFile.DirectoryName` with `$PWD.ProviderPath` in the `Join-Path` call.

Comment: Sorry but I'm stupid, I posted the code that I try to run but it doesn't work, where am I wrong?

Comment: @EdoardoEndrizzi, I've posted a complete solution in an update to the answer. Honestly, it sounds like you need help with the fundamentals, and you cannot generally expect such detailed guidance here. Also, please don't substantially alter your question after answers have been given: it makes the answer no longer match the question and causes confusion. I've reverted your question to its previous form.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just started.
Thanks for taking your time, of course I pointed to your answer as the solution.

Comment: Glad to hear we got there, @EdoardoEndrizzi; thanks for accepting.

Comment: Too bad that with -recurse I can't also apply it to subfolders. excellent script though.

Comment: Thanks, @EdoardoEndrizzi. It shouldn't be hard to adapt the solution to recursive processing: if you want to save the output files alongside the input files, replace `$OutDir` with `$csvFile.DirectoryName` in the `Join-Path` call. Otherwise, with a single output directory, you'd need to make sure there are no name collisions. If you get stuck implementing the latter, I encourage you to ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, fixed with your tip and adding -recurse after "$SourceDir".