# Modify the output of this script so that it is read as BOM-less UTF-8

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8, powershell-5.0, byte-order-mark

I have several .csv files in a folder with the second column empty and I would like to fill it with the data present in as many csv files with the same name+column3.

Example:

firstfile.csv

```
header1,translation,source
first,,"third"
one,,three
```

firstfile_column3.txt (name of the file+_column3.txt)

```
source
second, fifth
two
```

firstfileoutput.csv (source became translation)

```
header1,translation,source
first,"second, fifth","third"
one,two,three
```

I was able to get it to work, but the accents and Asian characters are wrong. I am using Powershell 5 on Windows and should modify the output so that it is read as BOM-less UTF-8.
Trying to edit the last few strings still can't solve it.

```
param(
    $SourceDir = $PWD,
    $OutDir = $PWD,
    $OutFileSuffix = "output" # Define the suffix for the output file.
)

# Get all primary CSV files in the source directory.
$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -Recurse -Filter "*.csv"

foreach ($csvFile in $csvFiles) {
    # Construct the name for the corresponding _column3 file.
    $column3FileName = "{0}_column3.txt" -f $csvFile.BaseName
    $column3FilePath = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath $column3FileName
    
    # Check if the _column3 file exists.
    if (Test-Path $column3FilePath) {
        # Import the primary CSV file and the corresponding _column3 file.
        $primaryCsv = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile.FullName
        $column3Data = Get-Content $column3FilePath
        
        # Assuming the first line in the _column3 file is a header and we skip it.
        $column3Values = $column3Data | Select-Object -Skip 1

        # Update the second column (translation) in the primary CSV with data from the _column3 file.
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $primaryCsv.Count; $i++) {
            $primaryCsv[$i].translation = $column3Values[$i]
        }

        # Construct the output file path.
        $outputFilePath = Join-Path -Path $csvFile.DirectoryName -ChildPath ("{0}{1}.csv" -f $csvFile.BaseName, $OutFileSuffix)

        # Export the updated CSV data to a new file.
        $primaryCsv | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Corresponding column3 file not found for $($csvFile.Name)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Encoding option on Import-CSV https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.4

Comment: I have already tried but I can't apply it correctly, it still gives me the letters coded incorrectly.

Comment: What tool are you using to read the file?  Is the tool using a font with the correct characters?  There is no encoding in your code.  Encoding takes bytes and converts to strings (or strings to bytes).  You code is reading strings from a files and writing the strings back to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **ensure consistent, *BOM-less UTF-8* handling in *Windows PowerShell***:

- On *reading*:

  - Use `-Encoding utf8` to ensure that BOM-less UTF-8 files are read as such:

    - `Import-Csv -Encoding utf8 $csvFile.FullName`
    - `Get-Content -Encoding utf8 $column3FilePath`
- On *writing*:

  - *Avoid* `-Encoding utf8`, because it creates files *with BOM*.
  - A non-obvious workaround for your `Export-Csv` call is needed, which relies on the fact that `New-Item` *does* create BOM-less UTF-8 files, by default and invariably:

    ```bash
     $null = New-Item -Force $outputFilePath -Value (
       $primaryCsv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-String
     )
    ```

Note that **none of these things are necessary in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, which **consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8**, across *all* built-in cmdlets (as well as when reading source code from files).

---

###### Background information:

- Unfortunately, *Windows PowerShell* and its file-reading cmdlets exhibit *inconsistent* behavior with respect to what character encoding to *assume* in the *absence of a BOM*.

  - In your code `Import-Csv` *happens to* assume UTF-8, ...
  - ... while `Get-Content` assumes *ANSI*, i.e. the system's active legacy ANSI code page, as does the PowerShell engine itself when it reads *source code*.
  - Similarly, there's no consistence when *writing to* files: `Set-Content` uses ANSI encoding, whereas `Out-File` (and its virtual aliases, `>` and `>>`)
- By contrast, [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) and its cmdlets - both reading and writing ones - now *consistently* default to *(BOM-less) UTF-8*

---

The **upshot** is:

- **In *Windows PowerShell*, to be safe, always use `-Encoding utf8` if you know  you're dealing with UTF-8-encoded files** - whether they do or do not have a BOM (in the former case, using `-Encoding utf8` is technically redundant, but causes no harm).

  - By contrast, this is no longer required in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, which in the absence of a BOM assumes UTF-8.
- The same applies if you want to ***write to* files** using UTF-8, but note that **in *Windows PowerShell* `-Encoding utf8` invariably creates UTF-8 files *with a BOM***:

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375) for *plain-text* workarounds (the `New-Item` workaround is shown above).
  - By contrast, *PowerShell (Core) 7+* creates *BOM-less* UTF-8 files both *by default* and with `-Encoding utf8`; in case you *do* want a BOM there, use `-Encoding utf8BOM`

Comment: OK, thank you. My mistake is that I was using Export-Csv instead of ConvertTo-Csv and I was not inserting -Encoding utf8 in the reading files.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @EdoardoEndrizzi. The `ConvertTo-Csv` + `New-Item` workaround isn't exactly obvious.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.4) for `Export-Csv` say the default `-Encoding` is `utf8NoBOM`, but you can also specify `utf8NoBOM` explicitly.

Comment: Indeed, @RemyLebeau: In PowerShell 7+, BOM-less UTF-8 is the default across _all_ built-in cmdlets, as well as when the PowerShell engine reads source code from files without a BOM; both `-Encoding utf8NoBom` and `-Encoding  utf8` request that default explicitly. Note that the equivalent of _Windows PowerShell's_ `-Encoding utf8` is `-Encoding utf8BOM` in PowerShell 7+ and, as explained in the answer, Windows PowerShell does _not_ offer writing _BOM-less_ UTF-8 files by way of an `-Encoding` argument, necessitating workarounds based on either `New-Item` or direct use of .NET APIs.