# PowerShell 5.1, Output to a text file with Out-File / Set-Content and utf8

Tags: powershell, text, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm a bit stumped at how to interpret this in PS 5.1:

First, I try to create a file with `Out-File` and then append to it with `Add-Content` and `Out-File -Append`:

```
"# Script for running installers`n`n" | Out-File $InstallTools -Encoding utf8
"sleep 5" | Add-Content $InstallTools
"Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden `"powershell.exe`" -ArgumentList `"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"`"$SetupScript`"`"`"" | 
  Out-File -Append $InstallTools
```

Output is a mess:

```
# Script for running installers
sleep 5
S t a r t - P r o c e s s   - W i n d o w S t y l e   H i d d e n   " p o w e r s h e l l . e x e "   - A r g u m e n t L i s t   " - N o P r o f i l e   - E x e c u t i o n P o l i c y   B y p a s s   - F i l e   " " C : \ U s e r s \ B o s s \ I n s t a l l   w i n f e t c h . p s 1 " " "
```

The `Add-Content` call works fine, whereas the `Out-File -Append` call causes the file corruption.

The above output is when I open in notepad. If I open in VS Code, it's worse; I see no text after the `sleep 5` just a load of nulls.

Why do the first 2 lines work fine, then the third is garbled, and how should I construct things to get meaningful output?

Edit: Believe I have resolved the problem, by adding `-Encoding utf8` to the `Out-File -Append` lines. I read somewhere that the `-Append` and `-Encoding` switches should not be used together, but it seems they must be to get consistent output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share how are defined variables `$InstallConsoleTools` and `$InstallTools`… Please share `$PSVersionTable` as well.

Comment: What output would you expect from your last line of code? I'd say you should remove the quotation marks around the command. ‍♂️

Comment: Those quotation marks are required as they are the arguments passed to the `powershell.exe` in the `Start-Process`. It's ugly for sure, but required, either that, or `"

Comment: So you don't want the command to be executed - you just want to appear it in your output file? Why don't you use single quotes for the outer qoutes and normal double quotes inside then?

Comment: Yes, so that I can run that output script later to process multiple commands that I want to run in parallel (with small pauses between each starting). It works quite well for my needs and ultimately processes things quite quickly for these jobs (and effectively less tricky and less resource intensive than `Start-Job`). You are right, I think I might get away with single outer quotes here, that's an oversight on my part, good point.

Comment: That sounds weird.    But since you seem to have solved your issue you may delete your question. ‍♂️

Comment: It's because I'm doing about 50 chocolatey installs, and they have a "no more than 20 installs per minute or you get a server timeout ban of 1 hour", so I run them in parallel but stagger them by having each install as a separate script, then run those scripts one by one with a 5 second pause to break the parallel processes up. Would love to see a better way, but that would be for another question indeed.

Comment: You should have started with that. ‍♂️

Comment: I did make the question about text / utf8 output itself, was not about the content of that text, but sure, I should have made it all agnostic outputs.

Comment: Use set-content (which you haven't) instead of out-file.  The code as written works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Believe I have resolved the problem, by adding `-Encoding utf8` to the `Out-File -Append` lines.

Indeed, that is the key to solving your problem, for the following reasons:

- If you use **[`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) `-Append`** to append to a preexisting file, you **must *explicitly* match the preexisting content's encoding with an `-Encoding` argument**, namely `-Encoding utf8` in your case.

  - **In the absence of an `-Encoding` argument, `Out-File` uses *its default encoding***, which is **"Unicode" (UTF-16LE) in *Windows PowerShell*** (resulting in your symptom), and **(BOM-less) UTF-8 in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**.
  - Note that `>` and `>>` are in effect aliases of `Out-File` and `Out-File -Append`, so the above applies to them too; you can only *indirectly* control their output encoding - which then affects `Out-File` calls too - via `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451413/45375) for details.
- By contrast, **[`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) *tries to match* the existing encoding**, in both PowerShell editions, but **what encoding it *assumes* in the *absence of a BOM* in the preexisting content differs by edition**:

  - *Windows PowerShell*: ANSI (the equivalent of `-Encoding Default`), same as [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)
  - *PowerShell 7+*: UTF-8

---

The **upshot** with respect to your scenario is:

- Since you're running *Windows PowerShell* and used `-Encoding utf8` to initially create your file, that file *has a BOM* (there is *no* `-Encoding` argument that would allow creation of *BOM-less* UTF-8 files in Windows PowerShell - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77950556/45375) for background information and workarounds).
- Thanks to the presence of a BOM, `Add-Content` was therefore able to unambiguously match the existing encoding, whereas `Out-File -Append` blindly used its Windows PowerShell default, UTF-16LE.
- With *text* as input, pairing [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) (for the initial file creation) with [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) (for appending) has fewer surprises and performs better than `Out-File`, and the `Add-Content` calls don't need `-Encoding` arguments.

  - However, in Windows PowerShell you need to use `-Encoding utf8` with `Set-Content` to ensure UTF-8 encoding (invariably *with a BOM*).
- None of the above problems would arise in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), which consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8, across all cmdlets; if you do want a BOM, use `-Encoding utf8BOM`

Comment: Very informative, thanks. But, what then is the actual point/usefulness of `Out-File`? Are there any scenarios where we should only use `Out-File` and not use `Set-Content`? I guess, if you want a mixture of encodings in a single file, then it might be desirable, but I cannot think of a situation where that would ever be useful.

Comment: @YorSubs, re `Out-File` vs. `Set-Content`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246434/45375.