# Need to substitute \x0d\x0a to \x2c\x0d\x0a in a file using powershell

Tags: powershell, replace, hex

Need to replace `\x0d\x0a` with `\x2c\x0d\x0a` in a file.

I can do it relatively easy on Unix:

```
awk '(NR>1){gsub("\r$",",\r")}1' $file > "fixed_$file":
```

Need help with implementing this in PowerShell.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I also encourage you to revisit your previous questions to see if answer there should be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're running this on *Windows* (where `\r\n` (CRLF) newlines are the default), the following command
is the equivalent of your `awk` command:

```
Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object { 
  if ($_.ReadCount -eq 1) { $_ } else { $_ -replace '$', ',' }
} | Set-Content "fixed_$file"
```

*Caveat*: The character encoding of the input file is *not* preserved, and
`Set-Content` uses a default, which you can override with `-Encoding`.
In *Windows PowerShell*, this default is the system's "ANSI" encoding, whereas in PowerShell *Core* it is BOM-less UTF-8.

- `Get-Content $file` reads the input file line by line.
- The `ForEach-Object` loop passes the 1st line (`$_.ReadCount -eq 1`) through as-is (`$_`), and appends `,` (which is what escape sequence `\x2c` in your `awk` command represents) to all others (`$_ -replace '$', ','`).

  - Note: `$_ + ','` or `"$_,"` are simpler alternatives for appending a comma; the regex-based 
    `-replace` operator was used here to highlight the PowerShell feature that is similar to `awk`'s `gsub()`.
- `Set-Content` then writes the resulting lines to the target file, terminating each with the platform-appropriate newline sequence, which on Windows is CRLF (`\r\n`).

Comment: i've been replacing \r\n  when i could have been replacing the regex $ all this time? THANK YOU!

Comment: @RobertCotterman: With line-by-line input: yes, given that lines are usually stripped of a trailing newline. However, if the input is a multi-line string and you want to match line endings, more work is needed.

Comment: Ah thanks. I also have NEVER used set-content, it seems it can't append, why would i use set-content rather than out-file? i mean there is add-content too, but this seems to get tricky. Why powershell? I tried to read the differences and there are some, but do you know of examples where one out weighs the other no matter what? (not a crazy answer needed, maybe you already wrote an answer somewhere?)

Comment: @RobertCotterman: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246434/45375

Comment: So it seems the 2 main reasons are encoding and speed. And since encoding is no longer an issue (lucky for me since I'm newer to powershell) it seems speed is the main benefit. And I suppose passthru. Thank you for some insight. I feel set-content proves veteranism.

Comment: @RobertCotterman: Yes, encoding differences do not affect PowerShell _Core_, but they will continue to plague _Windows PowerShell_. Also note that with _non-string_ types the fundamental difference between `Out-File` and `Set-Content` described in the linked answer will never go away.