# How to set encoding for a herestring/heredoc in powershell?

Tags: powershell, encoding, heredoc, herestring

I'm attempting to update the hosts file on a Windows server and trying to do it using a heredoc in powershell.

I can't figure out why my result has extra spaces between every character in each hosts entry.

I'm porting some scripting from Linux.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> cat C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\etchosts.ps1
@"
127.0.0.1 src.example.com
127.0.0.2 builds.example.com
127.0.0.3 ti.example.com
127.0.0.4 jira.example.com
"@ >>C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts



PS C:\Users\Administrator> powershell C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\etchosts.ps1
PS C:\Users\Administrator> cat C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#       127.0.0.1       localhost
#       ::1             localhost
 1 2 7 . 0 . 0 . 1   s r c . e x a m p l e . c o m

 1 2 7 . 0 . 0 . 2   b u i l d s . e x a m p l e . c o m

 1 2 7 . 0 . 0 . 3   t i . e x a m p l e . c o m

 1 2 7 . 0 . 0 . 4   j i r a . e x a m p l e . c o m
```

I expected no spaces between all the characters.
If there is a "Windows" way to do this, I would appreciate any input/suggestions.

Comment: `>>` -> `| Out-File -Encoding ASCII -Append`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules#here-strings) is just a special form of a PowerShell string literal, and like *all* strings in PowerShell and .NET (`System.String`), their in-memory encoding is *always* UTF-16.

- As an aside: For a string literal to be read into memory correctly, the enclosing script file must be properly encoded; the best choice is UTF-8 *with a BOM* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790355/45375).

However, **what matters is *how you write an (in-memory) string to a file***.

**`>> file` is effectively the same as `| Out-File -Append file`**, and in *Windows PowerShell* `Out-File` **defaults to UTF16-LE encoding ("Unicode")**, where each character is (typically) encoded with *2 bytes*. What appear to be spaces are actually the `NUL` (`0x0`) bytes in the 2nd byte of the encoding of each ASCII-range character.

- As an aside: In PowerShell *Core*, BOM-less UTF-8 is the - much more sensible - default; since UTF-8 is backward-compatible with characters in the ASCII range, your code would have worked fine in PowerShell Core.

By contrast, **`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` is ASCII-encoded** (1 byte per character).

To match that encoding, **use `Add-Content` instead of `>>`**:

```
@"
127.0.0.1 src.example.com
127.0.0.2 builds.example.com
127.0.0.3 ti.example.com
127.0.0.4 jira.example.com
"@ | Add-Content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Unlike `Out-File -Append`, `Add-Content` *matches* the encoding of a file's preexisting content (and, if there is none, defaults to the active ANSI code page's encoding ("Default") in Windows PowerShell, like `Set-Content`); in the absence of a BOM, as in this case, ANSI encoding is assumed, but with ASCII-range-only input characters that is effectively the same as ASCII, given that ANSI code pages are a superset of ASCII.

---

See also:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56944530/45375) to a closely related question.
- [This comprehensive overview of PowerShell's encoding behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375), including how to change the default encoding for `>` / `>>`.
- [This GitHub suggestion](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/3190) to add a conceptual help topic about character encoding to the official PowerShell documentation.

Comment: I feel like we need to take your best, most thorough post about encoding and sticky it somewhere. This comes up A LOT.

Comment: Thanks, @AdminOfThings. Ideally, the official documentation should provide this information, and there's an [open suggestion to add that](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/3190). In the meantime, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) probably provides the most comprehensive overview.

Comment: Thanks. This really helps. I was about to go down the path of installing wsl but since this is a script to configure an aws instance that install requires a reboot which complicates things. I do have a related question. I have this code in the userdata for the instance: @'
{{.sshconfig}}
'@ >C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config ... and this seems to have the correct encoding, Do you know why? (the {{.sshconfig}} gets replaced)

Comment: @mikedoy: Glad to hear it. `>C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config` would only work as expected (with ASCII-range-only chars.) if you used PowerShell _Core_, or, in Windows PowerShell v5.1, if you changed `>`'s encoding globally to ASCII or ANIS ("Default"), as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).

Answer (score 1):

I would never use "out-file -append" or ">>".  It doesn't check what the current encoding is.  This is a terrible idiosyncrasy of powershell 5.  Now you have a file mixed with ascii and unicode.  The spaces are actually nulls.  I prefer add-content in this case.  Add-content will check the BOM first.