# How can I keep UNIX LF line endings?

Tags: powershell, newline, line-endings

I have a large (9 GiB), ASCII encoded, pipe delimited file with UNIX-style line endings; 0x0A.

I want to sample the first 100 records into a file for investigation. The following will produce 100 records (1 header record and 99 data records). However, it changes the line endings to DOS/Winodws style; CRLF, 0x0D0A.

```
Get-Content -Path .\wellmed_hce_elig_20191223.txt |
    Select-Object -first 100 |
    Out-File -FilePath .\elig.txt -Encoding ascii
```

I know about iconv, recode, and dos2unix. Those programs are not on my system and are not permitted to be installed. I have searched and found a number of places on how to get to CRLF. I have not found anything on getting to or keeping LF.

How can I produce the file with LF line endings instead of CRLF?

Comment: Looks like [environment]::newline controls it, but it's read only.  You can always use a different os or WSL.

Comment: @js2010, if I cannot install iconv or dos2unix, do you really think I could install WSL or use a different OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join the lines from the Get-Content cmdlet with the Unix "`n" newline and save that.

Something like

```
((Get-Content -Path .\wellmed_hce_elig_20191223.txt | 
        Select-Object -first 100) -join "`n") |
        Out-File -FilePath .\elig.txt -Encoding ascii -NoNewLine
```

Comment: This works well except that the last record is left without an LF. I modified mine to use `-join "\`n") + "\`n" |` and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60157949/45375) with a **performance optimization** based on the little-used `-ReadCount` parameter:

```sh
Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding ascii .\outfile.txt -Value (
  (Get-Content -First 100 -ReadCount 100 .\file.txt) -join "`n") + "`n"
)
```

- `-First 100` instructs [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) to read (at most) `100` lines.
- `-ReadCount 100` causes these 100 lines to be read and emitted *together*, as an *array*, which speeds up reading and subsequent processing.

  - Note: In PowerShell [Core] v7.0+ you can use shorthand `-ReadCount 0` in combination with `-First <n>` to mean: read the requested `<n>` lines as a single array; due to a bug in earlier versions, including Windows PowerShell, `-ReadCount 0` always reads the *entire* file, even in the presence of `-First` (aka `-TotalCount` aka `-Head`).
    Also, even as of PowerShell [Core] 7.0.0-rc.2 (current as of this writing), combining `-ReadCount 0` with *`-Last <n>`* (aka `-Tail`) should be avoided (for now): while output produced is correct, *behind the scenes* it is again *the whole file* that is read; see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11830).
- Note the `` + "`n" ``, which ensures that the output file will have a *trailing* newline as well (which text files in the Unix world are expected to have).

While the above also works with `-Last <n>` (`-Tail <n>`) to extract from the *end* of the file, Theo's (slower) `Select-Object` solution offers more flexibility with respect to extracting *arbitrary ranges* of lines, thanks to available parameters `-Skip`, `-SkipLast`, and `-Index`; however, offering these parameters also *directly on `Get-Content`* for superior performance is being proposed in [this GitHub feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11750).

Also note that I've used `Set-Content` instead of `Out-File`.
**If you know you're writing *text*, `Set-Content` is sufficient and generally *faster*** (though in this case this won't matter, given that the data to write is passed as a *single* value).

For a comprehensive overview of the **differences between `Set-Content` and `Out-File` / `>`**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246434/45375).

---

**`Set-Content` vs. `Out-File` benchmark:**

Note: This benchmark compares the two cmdlets with respect to writing *many* input strings *received via the pipeline* to a file.

```sh
# Sample array of 100,000 lines.
$arr = (, 'foooooooooooooooooooooo') * 1e5
# Time writing the array lines to a file, first with Set-Content, then
# with Out-File.
$file = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
{ $arr | Set-Content -Encoding Ascii $file }, 
{ $arr | Out-File -Encoding Ascii $file } | % { (Measure-Command $_).TotalSeconds }
Remove-Item $file
```

Sample timing in seconds from my Windows 10 VM with Windows PowerShell v5.1:

```sh
2.6637108 # Set-Content
5.1850954 # Out-File; took almost twice as long.
```