# Special characters become question marks after Command line find and replace

Tags: powershell, cmd, automation

I have a text file `input.xlf`

```xml
  <trans-unit id="loco:5e7257a0c38e0f5b456bae94">
    &lt;source&gt;Login</source>
    <target>登入</target>
    <note>Login Header</note>
  </trans-unit>
```

Basically I need to replace `&lt;` with `<` and `&gt;` with '>', so I run below script

runner.bat

```sh
powershell -Command "(gc input.xlf) -replace '&lt;', '<' | Out-File -encoding ASCII output.xlf";
powershell -Command "(gc output.xlf) -replace '&gt;', '>' | Out-File -encoding ASCII  output.xlf";
```

The above was working until I noticed below as the output

```xml
  <trans-unit id="loco:5e7257a0c38e0f5b456bae94">
    <source>Login</source>
    <target>??????</target>
    <note>Login Header</note>
  </trans-unit>
```

I tried removing the encoding  but now I get

```xml
 <trans-unit id="loco:5e7257a0c38e0f5b456bae94">
   <source>Login</source>
   <target>ç™»å…¥</target>
   <note>Login Header</note>  
 </trans-unit>
```

Below is my desired output

```xml
  <trans-unit id="loco:5e7257a0c38e0f5b456bae94">
    <source>Login</source>
    <target>登入</target>
    <note>Login Header</note>
  </trans-unit>
```

Comment: You're encoding as `ASCII` which doesn't support unicode characters.

Comment: This happens because you use `-encoding ASCII`, did you try `-encoding UTF8`?

Comment: @tromgy Just tried it, I get  `ç™»å…¥` same as the result without the encoding

Comment: See if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476326/displaying-unicode-in-powershell) helps; not sure, and I'm not feeling really well so I don't want to focus too much on it, but it might help out.

Comment: Thanks @Tacoタコス The post has  a lot of helpful information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are **(potentially) *two* character-encoding problems**:

- On *output*, using `-Encoding Ascii` is *guaranteed* to "lossily" transliterate any non-ASCII-range characters to literal `?` characters.

  - To preserve all characters, you must choose a *Unicode* encoding, such as  `-Encoding Utf8`
- On *input*, you must ensure that the input file is correctly read by PowerShell.

  - Specifically, *Windows PowerShell* misinterprets *BOM-less* UTF-8 files as *ANSI*-encoded, so you need to use `-Encoding Utf8` with `Get-Content` too.

Additionally, you can get away with a *single* `powershell.exe` call, and you can additionally *optimize* this call:

```
powershell -Command "(gc -Raw -Encoding utf8 input.xlf) -replace '&lt;', '<' -replace '&gt;', '>' | Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding Utf8 output.xlf"
```

- Using `-Raw` with `gc` ([`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)) reads the file *as a whole* instead of into an *array of lines*, which speeds up the `-replace` operations.
- You can *chain* [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operations
- With input that is already text (strings), [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) is generally the faster choice.<sup>[1]</sup>
  `-NoNewLine` prevents an extra trailing newline from getting appended.

---

<sup>[1] It will make virtually no difference here, given that only
a *single* string is written, but with many input strings (line-by-line output) it may - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60158247/45375).</sup>

Comment: This is very helpful given that this are translation files and they are quite big

Comment: Glad to hear it, @OwenKelvin. Yes, `-Raw` makes a big difference. The only caveat is that the file's content must fit into memory as a whole (actually _three_ times here, given that each `-replace` operation creates a copy), but even large text files are quite likely to fit. (Your own approach without `-Raw` _also_ loads the entire file, due to enclosing the `Get-Content` call in `(...)`, though that could be transformed into a _streaming_ approach where each line at a time is processed and saved to the target file, without needing to store the entire file's content in memory at once.)