# How to invoke-sqlcmd and export WITH headers and dashes/hyphens but tab-delimited

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

Say I run this:

```
$HOME_DATABASE = 'mydb' 
$params = @{
    'Database' = $HOME_DATABASE
    'ServerInstance' = 'mydb'
    'Username' = 'myuser'
    'Password' = 'mypass'
    'Query' = 'select * from sometable'
}
$queryresults = Invoke-Sqlcmd @params
```

I want the output to look like:

```
Name    Date    Number of Records   95th Percentile 99.5th Percentile   100th Percentile
----    ----    -----------------   --------------- -----------------   ----------------
asdf    2022-10-02 00:00:00.000 1234    5678    9012    12345
```

where what's separating the fields is a tab.

I tried this, but it doesn't include the hyphen/dash line.

```
$queryresults |ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -delimiter "$query_result_separator" | `
 ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace('"','')} | `
 Out-file c:\temp\$($query_attachment_filename) -fo -en ascii
```

Somebody else said to export-csv, then go back and replace the quotes in the file. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) and [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) (the former's in-memory counterpart) by design do *not* create a *separator line* between their header row and the data rows, given that the sole purpose of such a line would be to make the the data *human-friendly*, whereas CSV / TSV data is meant for *programmatic processing*.

- To get such a line, you'll have to insert it *manually*.

Also, both cmdlets `"..."`-enclose all field values - *invariably* in *Windows PowerShell*, *by default* in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.

- In *PowerShell (Core) 7+* you can use `-UseQuotes Never` as an *opt-out* of this behavior.
- In *Windows PowerShell* you need to remove the `"` chars. *after the fact*, as you do in your own solution attempt.

---

A solution that works in *both* PowerShell editions:

```bash
$i = 0
$queryresults |
  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t" |
  ForEach-Object { 
    $_ -replace '"' # output with " chars. removed
    # If it was the first, i.e. the *header* row that was just output,
    # construct and output the desired separator row.
    if ($i++ -eq 0) {
      ($_ -replace '"' -split "`t").ForEach({ '-' * $_.Length }) -join "`t"
    }
  }
```

Pipe to [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) as needed (which is preferable to [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file), given that it is *strings* that are to be saved - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60158247/45375)).

Comment: you are a stone-cold genius.  I never would've considered doing that, but it's super-obvious and would've taken me a good day to figure out. THANK YOU!