# powershell ignore character escaping with output from a different process

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, drone.io

I have a process running powershell commands with input from a config file. (In casu it's a drone CI executor on Windows with a drone YML file). This process sets an environment variable but I think this environment variable contains backticks which are interpreted as escape characters by powershell.

Since it's an OpenSSH key, this corrupts the key. Is there a way to treat the contents of the environment variable entirely as raw? Either during setting or reading (because since I don't know the key I do not know where it happens).

Drone CI config:

```yaml
  - name: copy to archive on remote host
    commands:
      - Write-Output $env:SSH_KEY > ssh_key
      - scp -i ssh_key file.zip user@host:/path/to/file.zip
      - rm ssh_key
    environment:
      SSH_KEY:
        from_secret: ssh_key
```

I know it's a functional key because it works on my linux containers. But on Windows the format is deemed invalid.

Comment: How about sharing code and sample data? ... you know ... a kind of [mre] ... 

Comment: @Olaf added, but it's quite a complex question since it relies on a lot of integration, there's not a lot of code I can share

Comment: @mklement0 that was it! It writes an UTF-16LE and the current Windows implementation of ssh requires an UTF-8. You indeed need to use `-Encoding ASCII` instead of `-Encoding UTF8` because the latter will create an UTF8-BOM file which again will be invalid for ssh purposes. Since an SSH key uses a characterset wholly contained in ASCII, it is safe to use this encoding. If you want to write this as an answer I'll accept it (or can do so myself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the behavior of `>`, the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), in PowerShell, which is in effect an alias of the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet:

- Character encoding:

  - In *Windows PowerShell* (`powershell.exe`), it defaults to creating UTF16-LE ("Unicode") files, which most command-line utilities do not recognize.
  - In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (`pwsh`), it now - fortunately - defaults to BOM-less UTF-8, which is now the consistent default for all cmdlets, as well as for the PowerShell engine itself with respect to readings source code.
  - As an aside: In Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) up to v7.3.x, the PowerShell pipeline and `>` never act as a *raw byte conduit* for relaying raw data from *external programs*: such data is invariably *decoded into a .NET string* first, which `>` / `Out-File` then write to a file based on *their* default encoding. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for background.
- Trailing newline:

  - In both editions, a platform-native *newline* is appended to the input (each input object) by default on writing the file, which can be suppressed with the `-NoNewLine` switch.

---

The simplest solution is to use [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) instead, as it - surprisingly - creates BOM-less UTF-8 files even in *Windows PowerShell*, and never appends a trailing newline (`-ItemType File` is implied):<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
$env:SSH_KEY | New-Item -Force ssh_key
```

Note:

- `-Force` is needed in order to ensure that a preexisting file by that name is overwritten. However, `-Force` also creates a non-existent target *directory* on demand, which `>` / `Out-File` won't do.
- In *Windows PowerShell*, using `Out-File` (or [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content), which is generally preferable for text-only input)<sup>[2]</sup> with `-Encoding Utf8` is *not* an option, because the resulting file is invariably created *with a BOM*.
- Given that *PowerShell (Core) 7+* defaults to BOM-less UTF-8, there you could alternatively use:

  ```bash
  $env:SSH_KEY | Set-Content -NoNewLine ssh_key
  ```

  - *Assuming that* the input string contains ASCII-range characters only, this will also work in *Windows PowerShell*, because `Set-Content` defaults to the *ANSI* code page, as determined by the legacy system locale, which is a *superset* of ASCII.<sup>[3]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, this only applies if PowerShell's [current location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Locations) is one backed by the [file-system provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_FileSystem_Provider) - however, in practice it almost always is. If it isn't and you still want to create a *file*, either specify a *full* file-system path or prefix a relative one with `FileSystem::` in order to target the file-system provider's current directory.</sup>

<sup>[2] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60158247/45375) for background.</sup>

<sup>[3] This implies, unfortunately, that in *Windows PowerShell* different cmdlets have *different default encodings* - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for background.</sup>

Comment: Excellent write up. I'd like to add that the trailing newlines did not in fact corrupt the keyfile at least not as far as my SSH version's implementation is concerned. But good to know anyway!

Comment: Thanks, @bluppfisk, and thanks for the feedback on the trailing newline - I've removed the sentence from the answer.