# Powershell: smaller file takes 30x longer to write with 'Out-File'

Tags: performance, powershell, file-writing

I'm getting the contents of a file and keeping just the lines that match a regex or empty line. But writing the results, e.g. smaller amount of data, is taking ages...
Here is the code in question (I've added a few lines for debugging/measuring):

```
$original = Get-Content "$localDir\$ldif_file"
(Measure-Command -Expression { $original | Out-File "$localDir\Original-$ldif_file" }).TotalSeconds
$lines = ($original | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
"lines of `$original = $lines"

# Just keep lines of interest:
$stripped = $original | select-string -pattern '^custom[A-Z]','^$' -CaseSensitive
$lines = ($stripped | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
"lines of `$stripped = $lines"
(Measure-Command -Expression { $stripped | Out-File "$localDir\Stripped-$ldif_file" }).TotalSeconds

"done"
```

Problem: it takes for the smaller ($stripped) data 342 seconds to be written to a file (about 30 times longer than the $original data)! See output below:

```
11.5371677
lines of $original = 188715
lines of $stripped = 126404
342.6769547
done
```

Why is the Out-File of $stripped so much slower than the one of $original?
How to improve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting that select-string's matchinfo objects and out-file take so much longer.  I guess out-file does some extra rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60778905/45375):

- In **PowerShell 7+**, [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) now supports the **`-Raw` switch**, which **outputs *just strings*** (the matching lines), which should greatly speed up the command.

  - In ***Windows PowerShell***, less efficiently, you can **enclose the `Select-String` call in `(...).Line`** to get the lines as strings only.
  - Also note that **`Select-String` will be much faster if you directly pass it a *file path*** (so that it reads the file itself) rather than piping individual lines via `Get-Content`.
- Generally, for **writing objects that are already *strings*, `Set-Content` is the better - and faster - choice** compared to `Out-File`.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246434/45375) for background information and the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for a performance comparison.
  - **Character-encoding caveat** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for background):

    - In *Windows PowerShell*, `Set-Content` defaults to ANSI encoding, whereas `Out-File` defaults to "Unicode" (UTF-16LE); use `-Encoding` as needed.
    - Fortunately, *PowerShell [Core] 6+* uses a consistent default, namely UTF-8 without BOM.
- Passing collections *through the pipeline* can be slow; **for collections *already in memory in full* it is noticeably faster to pass them as *as a whole*, as an *argument* instead - *assuming the target cmdlet supports that*** - `Set-Content`'s `-Value` parameter *does*.

To put it all together:

```
# *PowerShell 7*: Use -Raw to directly get the lines as string.
$stripped = $original | 
  Select-String -Raw -Pattern '^custom[A-Z]','^$' -CaseSensitive

# *Windows PowerShell*: Use (...).Line to get the lines as strings.
$stripped = ($original | 
  Select-String -Pattern '^custom[A-Z]','^$' -CaseSensitive).Line

$lines = $stripped.Count # Simply count the array elements == number of lines.
"lines of `$stripped = $lines"

(Measure-Command -Expression { 
  Set-Content "$localDir\Stripped-$ldif_file" -Value $stripped
}).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. I need to stick to Windows Powershell for now, but with your recommendations (.Line and Set-Contents) now the file is written under a second!

Answer (score 1):

You're really comparing apples and oranges here.

`$original` contains 189K *strings*, but $stripped contains 126K `MatchInfo` objects that will have to be converted to strings one-by-one in the pipeline.

Use the `-cmatch` operator instead to retain the original string input values and you'll find it's much faster to output them to a file:

```
$original = Get-Content "$localDir\$ldif_file"
(Measure-Command -Expression { $original | Out-File "$localDir\Original-$ldif_file" }).TotalSeconds
$lines = ($original | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
"lines of `$original = $lines"

# Just keep lines of interest:
$stripped = $original |Where-Object {$_ -cmatch '^custom[A-Z]' -or $_ -like ''}
$lines = ($stripped | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
"lines of `$stripped = $lines"
(Measure-Command -Expression { $stripped | Out-File "$localDir\Stripped-$ldif_file" }).TotalSeconds

"done"
```

Comment: Thanks, the file writing is indeed much faster but the pattern matching in this case is taking much longer. There's no real improvement overall.

Answer (score 0):

### "Burst Mode"

To boost the `Set-Content` and `Out-File` cmdlets with another **factor 2** on top of what is already answered here. Try this [`Create-Batch` cmdlet](https://github.com/iRon7/Create-Batch):

```
Install-Script -Name Create-Batch

$lines |Create-Batch |Set-Content .\lines.txt
```

This creates a single batch (array) containing all the items
The result of this statement is the same as: `Get-Process |Set-Content .\Process.txt`
But note that this appears (for yet unknown reason) **about twice as fast**
even if you partual limit the memory usage by setting e.g. `-Size 10000`.
See: [`#18070` Possible Set/Add-Content performance improvement](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18070)