Powershell pipeline accumulating buffer
Take basic pipeline:
CommandA | CommandB

CommandA is slow++ while CommandB requires user input to proceed. When CommandB proceeds to the next pipeline item it experiences considerable delay while CommandA does it's thing. The whole pipeline seems proceed on a one at a time basis.
I'd like to do something like:
CommandA | PrefetchPipeline -size 10 | CommandB

So that PrefetchPipeline buffers up to 10 items from CommandA but immediately gives the next item to CommandB whenever possible. There should be no delay for the first item but then if CommandB takes a lot of time to complete it's process, items should still be fetched in the background from CommandA.
Is this possible in powershell?
Clarification:
1..100 | foreach-object { Start-Sleep 3; $_ } |
  MagicFunction |
  foreach-object { write-host $_; [void]$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey() }

Can one write a MagicFunction that accumulates stuff from the left and sends it to the right as soon as possible. So that if you wait 30 sec. without pressing a key then you get 10 items in quick succession (i.e. without waiting 3s for each) but without introducing additional delays (i.e. we don't want the MagicFunction to just wait until it has X number of items and then release them all at once).

Does this answer your question: Slice a PowerShell array into groups of smaller arrays (also note: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73732564/1701026)

Sounds like you're basically looking for ForEach-Object -Parallel...

@iRon, i don't think so, I don't want classic buffering as in collect until there's X items and then send all X in one batch/burst, I'd like CommandA to continue working on up to 10 items but not delay flow until there actually is 10 items. CommandB should be getting new stuff as soon as possible.

@SantiagoSquarzon Not sure how Parallel would help here. CommandB is sequential in nature. Even if you get things in parallel from CommandA you'd need to gather it up and make it sequential again keeping the original order. I'm open to suggestions though!

All output piped from Parallel loop is already sequential, the pipeline makes it so. CommandA | % -Parallel { do stuff } -ThrottleLimit 10 | CommandB is perfectly valid code.

I don't  that CommandA (or rhe suggested PrefetchPipeline) cmdlet has any knowledge of the idle state of CommandB. But as the CommandB is appearently the bottleneck, I would put the suggest buffer logic in the procces block of CommandB.

@SantiagoSquarzon Nice! At first glance CommandA | % -Parallel { $_ } -ThrottleLimit 10 | CommandB is indeed what I'm looking for, if you'd like to write and answer it looks like a winner :)

Your new edit implies that the processing part is happening before MagicFunction, the parallel loop is meant to split the work among multiple threads. The first loop should be the one where you use -Parallel

The PowerShell pipeline is inherently synchronous, so only one command in the chain can run at any given time (even using ForEach-Object -parallel the pipeline as a whole is still synchronous).
With PowerShell (Core) 7+, you may implement an asynchronous producer/consumer pattern using a thread job and a thread-safe collection:
# Create a thread-safe collection (queue) with an upper limit of 5 items
$buffer = [Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection[int]]::new( 5 )

# Start producer as a background thread
$job = Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock { 
    
    1..100 | ForEach-Object {
        
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1  # simulate a slow operation

        ($using:buffer).Add( $_ )
    }

    # Signal that we have finished using the buffer
    ($using:buffer).CompleteAdding()
}

# Consumer loop runs until producer thread calls CompleteAdding() and
# the buffer is empty.
while( -not $buffer.IsCompleted ) {

    # Fetch and output any new items from the buffer
    $item = 0
    while( $buffer.TryTake( [ref] $item ) ) { 
        Write-Host "Received: $item"
    }

    Write-Host "Press any key to fetch the next batch of items..."
    $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()
}

# Cleanup
$job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob 
$buffer.Dispose()


The producer is allowed to enqueue a maximum of 5 items (as specified by the BlockingCollection constructor argument). If the queue is full, it has to wait until the consumer removes an item.
Using the TryTake() method, the consumer won't block if there are no items in the queue. If there are items in the queue, it will remove each item and output it. Use the Take() method instead if you want the consumer to wait until a new item is in the queue.
While the consumer blocks during the ReadKey() call, the producer thread is still able to enqueue new items.
The using: prefix is necessary to reference the $buffer variable from inside the thread jobs script block.


Thanks! I've also found there is another pattern for consuimg items from the collection foreach ($item in $buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable()) { ... } which nicely fits my use case.

Based on comments, what it seemed you were looking for is parallel processing of pipeline input object in which case PowerShell 7 comes with built-in -Parallel parameter on ForEach-Object and with -ThrottleLimit you can control how many tasks can run at a time, in essence your code could be:
CommandA |
    ForEach-Object -Parallel { ...action per input object... } -ThrottleLimit 10 |
    CommandB

If you're on Windows PowerShell 5.1 you can look at PSParallelPipeline as a replacement since there is no -Parallel parameter there.

Thanks! However after some more checking here's a counter example 1..100 | foreach-object { Start-Sleep 3; $_ } | foreach-object -parallel { $_ } -ThrottleLimit 10 | foreach-object { write-host $_; [void]$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey() }. No matter how long I wait, after i press a button I still have to wait 3 seconds for the next item.

It looks like you need to use -Parallel inside CommandA then instead of after it @user2847643. ReadKey() will be invoked per pipeline object tho
