# Command console output -- to file . Get { Windows Filtering Platform / Windows Firewall } rules

Tags: powershell

Output of this doesn't fit into the window

```
get-netFirewallRule | where { $_.Action -eq 'Block' -and $_.Enabled -eq 'True' }

read-host -prompt "Press Enter to continue..."
```

When i try

```
Remove-Item -Path ($env:userprofile + "\Desktop\enabledBlockRules_WindowsFilteringPlatform.txt")

get-netFirewallRule | where { $_.Action -eq 'Block' -and $_.Enabled -eq 'True' } | forEach {
    $_ | Add-Content -Path ($env:userprofile + "\Desktop\enabledBlockRules_WindowsFilteringPlatform.txt") -Encoding "utf8"
}

read-host -prompt "Exported to desktop ."
```

I get nonsense results . How could i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To streamline your answer and add some context:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule | 
  Where-Object { $_.Action -eq 'Block' -and $_.Enabled } | 
    Out-File -Encoding utf8 -FilePath "$env:userprofile\Desktop\enabledBlockRules_WindowsFilteringPlatform.txt"
```

Note how `Out-File` is *directly* piped to, which obviates the need for removing the output file first and the inefficient loop with `-Append`.

As for **why switching from `Add-Content` to `Out-File` made the difference**:

- [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) / [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) perform **simple `.ToString()` stringification** of its input objects, which for complex objects more often than not results in ***unhelpful* string representations**.
- By contrast, [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) (`>`) / `Out-File -Append` (`>>`) use the usual for-display **output-formatting system**, yielding the **same rich formatting you'd see when outputting to the console**.

  - Do note, however, that these representations are for the *human observer*, and therefore not generally suited to *programmatic processing*; for the latter, use a *structured* text format, such as CSV or JSON.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246434/45375) for more information, including about the different default character encodings between the cmdlets in Windows PowerShell.

Comment: I was worrying about any size-per-operation limitations, thats why used foreach

Comment: @irvnriir, the pipeline _streams_ output objects, so that `Out-File` writes them to the file _one by one_, _as they're being received_, so there should be no concern about the overall size of the input. I assume that's what you meant, right? Also note that with per-object `Out-File` calls that result in _tabular_ formatting (not in your case), you'll get a header for each and every object.

Answer (score 0):

damn

```
Remove-Item -Path ($env:userprofile + "\Desktop\enabledBlockRules_WindowsFilteringPlatform.txt")

get-netFirewallRule | where { $_.Action -eq 'Block' -and $_.Enabled -eq 'True' } | forEach {
    $_ | Out-File -FilePath ($env:userprofile + "\Desktop\enabledBlockRules_WindowsFilteringPlatform.txt") -Encoding "utf8" -Append
}

read-host -prompt "Exported to desktop ."
```

Comment: You can use `Write-Host` instead of `Read-Host`. You also should be evaluating a against a boolean value so use `$true` instead of `'true'`.

Comment: @Abraham Zinala `Write-Host` doesn't pause the script .