# What is the difference in result by write-host and write-output?

Tags: powershell, write-host

I am new to PowerShell and while doing some code I came through this thing.
While I use `Write-Host` and `Write-Output` to perform the same query, I get different results:

```
PS> Write-Output $PSVersionTable                                                                                                                   

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                                                               
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117                                                                                                                                          
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                             
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.117
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.17929
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                 
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                 
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

vs.

```
PS> Write-Host $PSVersionTable                                                                                                                   
System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
```

Answer (score 2):

**Important difference**:

Write-output writes an object to the pipeline, so the next command can accept it as it's input. 
While Write-host just write directly to the console.

**In your example**

Write-Output will write the object to the pipeline, and Out-Default (Hidden at the end of the pipeline) will display the object values in either a table or a list.

Write-Host writes directly to the console instead of using the default cmdlet Out-default in the end of the pipeline. In other words,  Write-Host does not write anything to the pipeline, only displays what he sees to the console.. 
This is why you can add parameters like -foregroundcolor to the Write-Host cmdlet,  but not to the Write-output cmdlet.

**Write-Host** is useful when debugging and you need to display text in diffrent colors.

You can simply test this with

```
Write-Output "Hello World" | Get-Member
```

We can se that this is a System.String Object.

If we run:

```
Write-Host "Hello World" | Get-Member
```

We get an error: 
gm : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet ...

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two top results when doing a google search:

[PowerShell difference between Write-Host and Write-Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754069/powershell-difference-between-write-host-and-write-output)

[Which should I use: "Write-Host", "Write-Output", or "[console]::WriteLine"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755497/which-should-i-use-write-host-write-output-or-consolewriteline)

*Edit:
`Write-Host` does not support the data type of `$PSVersionTable` while `Write-Output` does. To see which one supports which data type you can use

```
Get-Help Write-Host
Get-Help Write-Output
```

Comment: Eric I have already checked these. Please check the image that I have uploaded along with the question. Thnx anyways

Comment: Ah, I didn't view the picture, I've added a few rows to my answer now.

Comment: Quibble: It's not that `Write-Host` doesn't _support_ `[System.Management.Automation.PSVersionHashTable]`, the data type of `$PSVersionTable`; it simply stringifies it in a way that isn't helpful to the human observer, mainly because it is typically used for printing _strings_; both `Write-Host` and `Write-Output` support (accept) instances of _any_ type, but (a) their way of stringifying them differs and (b) - more importantly - **`Write-Output` and `Write-Host` serve very different purposes** (as the linked articles explain, but not your answer per se).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already know that **`Write-Host` and `Write-Output` have *different purposes***; in short:

- To **produce *(data) output*, simply use a command or expression as-is**, which *implicitly* outputs it to the success (data) output stream - **explicit use of `Write-Output` is rarely needed**:

  - Instead of `Write-Output $PSVersionTable`, you can simply use `$PSVersionTable` by itself.
- **`Write-Host`, in PSv4-**, **prints directly to the *host*** (e.g., the console), bypassing PowerShell's output streams, which is why [it should generally be avoided](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/). While **it *is* integrated into PowerShell's output streams since v5, via *new* stream #6**, it's better to use its successor, [`Write-Information`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Information?view=powershell-5.1) - unless you need to produce console-only output for creating interactive experiences, such as writing prompt strings, espically if *colored* display is needed.

---

**To explain the difference in *console output*:**

- **`Write-Output`**, just like implicit output, **uses PowerShell's [default output formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml)**, which typically provides a much **friendlier representation** than just calling `.ToString()` on the underlying .NET type instances - see [`Get-Help about_Format.ps1xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-5.1)

  - `$PSVersionTable.GetType().FullName` tells us that `$PSVersionTable` is an instance of `[System.Management.Automation.PSVersionHashTable]`, which derives from `[System.Collections.Hashtable]`, which PowerShell's default formatting renders in a 2-column table layout.
- **`Write-Host` essentially calls just `.ToString()` on its arguments**, which in many cases simply prints the *full type name* of an object.

  - Calling `.ToString()` on a `[System.Management.Automation.PSVersionHashTable]` instance would yield just `'System.Management.Automation.PSVersionHashTable'`.
    However, [`Write-Host` prints the elements of objects that support the `[IEnumerable]` interface *individually*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master@%7B2017-09-26%7D/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WriteConsoleCmdlet.cs#L87-L106).
  - Thus, *each entry* in `$PSVersionTable` is *printed separately*, and since entries are of type `[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]`, which also stringifies to simply the type's full name - `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` -  you get a space-separated list of these strings (because `Write-Host` generally joins distinct outputs with a single space each).

Note that you can explicitly request a *string* representation of PowerShell's default output formatting via the `Out-String` cmdlet.

Therefore, aside from the stream-integration aspect, the following `Write-Host` command produces the same *console* output as `Write-Output $PSVersionTable` (or, simply: `$PSVersionTable`):

```bash
Write-Host ($PSVersionTable | Out-String)
```

**Another important difference** is that **if you pass *multiple* objects or *arrays* (enumerables) as *arguments*** (rather than via the pipeline):

- **`Write-Output` formats each input object *individually***, as in the pipeline; e.g., `Write-Output 1, 2` yields *two* lines:

  ```bash
  1
  2
  ```
- **`Write-Host` prints a single, space-separated list** of the stringified input objects; e.g., `Write-Host 1, 2` yields a *single* line:

  ```bash
  1 2
  ```

The same applies if you pass these value as *individual* arguments (rather than as an *array*); that is, `Write-Output 1 2` and `Write-Host 1 2` yield the same respective output.

Answer (score 0):

And another good article:
[Which Write Is Right For PowerShell?](https://www.petri.com/which-write-is-right)

In short $PSVersionTable return hash table (collection of objects). Write-host command is trying to convert everything to string and then to show it at the console, but you can not convert the whole hash-table directly to string.

Write-Output directly send this hash table to console without trying to change it.