# If I run a Python script from Powershell via the call operator ($val = & python myscript.py) - How can I pass in an array to $val from Python?

Tags: python, powershell

Here's a sample script:

```
import os
import sys
import pathlib
import json
from contextlib import redirect_stderr
from fontTools import ttLib
from fontmeta import FontMeta

# Check for commandline argument
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print('No argument was supplied.')
    exit(0)

fontfile = sys.argv[1]


def font_name(font_path, name_idx):
    font = ttLib.TTFont(font_path, ignoreDecompileErrors=True)
    with redirect_stderr(None):
        names = font['name'].names

    details = {}
    for x in names:
        if x.langID == 0 or x.langID == 1033:
            try:
                details[x.nameID] = x.toUnicode()
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                details[x.nameID] = x.string.decode(errors='ignore')
    # details[4] = Full Name
    # details[1] = Family Name
    # details[2] = Style Name
    return details[name_idx]


meta_instance = FontMeta(fontfile)

metadata = meta_instance.get_full_data()

fontFullName           = font_name(fontfile,4)
fontFamily             = font_name(fontfile,1)
fontStyle              = font_name(fontfile,2)
fontVers               = metadata[5]['value'];
fontVers               = fontVers.replace('Version ',"v")
fontLang               = metadata[1]['language']['value'];
fontUniqueID           = metadata[3]['value']
fontPostscriptName     = metadata[6]['value']
fontPostscriptEncoding = metadata[6]['encoding']['value']
fontDesigner           = metadata[9]['value']
fontLicenseURL         = metadata[14]['value']

print('Full Name:     ' + fontFullName)
print('Family:        ' + fontFamily)
print('Style:         ' + fontStyle)
print('Version:       ' + fontVers)
print('Language:      ' + fontLang)
print('UniqueID:      ' + fontUniqueID)
print('License URL:   ' + fontLicenseURL)
print('Font Designer: ' + fontDesigner)
```

**Output:**

```
Full Name:     Sharp Sans Bold
Family:        Sharp Sans
Style:         Bold
Version:       v1.001
Language:      English/United States
UniqueID:      1.001;2016;SHRP;SharpSans-Bold
License URL:   http://www.sharptype.co
Font Designer: Lucas Sharp
```

ps1:

```
& "D:\Dev\Python\00 VENV\FontTools\Scripts\Activate.ps1"

$val = python "D:\Dev\Python\Font Scripts\GetFontInfo.py" "D:\Fonts\00 Test\SharpSans-Bold.otf"

Write-Host "`$val:" $val -ForegroundColor Green
```

Right now the Python code is just printing values. My PS script is echoing the printed values as a string. Is there a way to pass these values to powershell other than just printing them - I.E. as an array?

Or should I return JSON and parse it in PowerShell?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When PowerShell invokes an *external program*, it streams the individual lines of its stdout output *one by one*** to PowerShell's pipeline.

If you *capture* this stream via *assignment to a variable*:

- *two or more* lines become an *array* (of type `[object[]]`) storing the lines.
- *one* line is stored as-is, as a *string* (type `[string]`).

Therefore:

```
$val = python "D:\Dev\Python\Font Scripts\GetFontInfo.py" "D:\Fonts\00 Test\SharpSans-Bold.otf"
```

***by itself* is sufficient to capture the stdout output lines from your `python` call as an array - assuming there are *two or more lines*.**

If you want to **ensure that `$val` is *always* an array - even if there's only *one* output line**, you have two options:

- Either: Use **`@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--)**:

```
$val = @(python "D:\Dev\Python\Font Scripts\GetFontInfo.py" "D:\Fonts\00 Test\SharpSans-Bold.otf")
```

- Or: Use an **`[array]` type constraint** (equivalent to `[object[]]`):

```
[array] $val = python "D:\Dev\Python\Font Scripts\GetFontInfo.py" "D:\Fonts\00 Test\SharpSans-Bold.otf"
```

**Note**:

- There are subtle differences between the two approaches above - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375) for details.
- When PowerShell captures or redirects output from external programs, decoding into .NET strings based on the character encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` is invariably involved - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905220/45375).
- To verify that `$val` is indeed an array, run `$val.GetType().FullName`.
- To print each array element on it own line, do *not* use [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host), simply submit `$val` *on its own* (which is equivalent to using [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output)  `$val`, though the latter's explicit use is rarely needed - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45829541/45375) for background information.

Comment: I can always tell it's you without looking at the username by the thoroughness of your answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can print the values line by line and split the output by newline as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252620/powershell-split-specify-a-new-line):

```
$arr = $val.Split([Environment]::NewLine)
```

Comment: `$val = python ...` - due to capturing the output from a call to an _external program_ - _by default_ stores an _array of lines_ in `$val` (assuming two or more output lines). Your solution is an unnecessary and expensive no-op, because - due to [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) - it makes the `.Split()` call on _each and every output line_, and each such line by definition does not contain any newlines.