# write-output - nonewline variable between text quotation marks

Tags: powershell, variables

I'm writing a PowerShell file that creates a batch file having variables between texts that includes quotation marks.

Please see below the script so that you can understand what I mean.

```
$addnewcomputerhere = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input new computername'
$addnewusernamehere = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input new username'
Write-Output 'powershell -Command "(gc sourcechangeme.txt) -replace ''newcomputername'', '''$addnewcomputerhere'''| Out-File source1changeme.txt"' | Add-Content edittextdone.bat
Write-Output 'powershell -Command "(gc sourcechangeme.txt) -replace ''newusername'', '''$addnewusernamehere'''| Out-File source1changeme.txt"' | Add-Content edittextdone.bat
```

Running the script `edittextdone.bat` should then look like this:

```
powershell -Command "(gc sourcechangeme.txt) -replace 'newcomputername', 'thecomputernamethathasbeengivenonprompt'| Out-File source1changeme.txt"
powershell -Command "(gc sourcechangeme.txt) -replace 'newusername', 'theusernamethathasbeengivenonprompt'| Out-File source1changeme.txt"
```

Instead of that it looks like this:

```
powershell -Command "(gc sourcechangeme.txt) -replace 'newcomputername', '
thecomputernamethathasbeengivenonprompt'| Out-File source1changeme.txt"
powershell -Command "(gc sourcechangeme.txt) -replace 'newusername', '
theusernamethathasbeengivenonprompt'| Out-File source1changeme.txt"
```

My problem is that the variables start new lines.

I was searching for any advice and went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150255/avoiding-newline-in-write-output) with no luck.

I've also read about `-NoNewline`, but couldn't figure out how to use it correctly.

Comment: So you are running Powershell to create a batch file that runs Powershell again?  Not quite understanding the point of that.  This question really no batch-file code, so I would remove the batch-file tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on implicit string concatenation. Use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`) for inserting values into your output strings:

```
'powershell -Command "(gc sourcechangeme.txt) -replace ''newcomputername'', ''{0}''| Out-File source1changeme.txt"' -f $addnewcomputerhere | Add-Content edittextdone.bat
'powershell -Command "(gc sourcechangeme.txt) -replace ''newusername'', ''{0}''| Out-File source1changeme.txt"' -f $addnewusernamehere | Add-Content edittextdone.bat
```

Comment: It's a good idea, however this didn't work either. I've got the following result:

powershell -Command "(gc sourcechangeme.txt) -replace 'newcomputername', '{0}'| Out-File source1changeme.txt"
-f
userinputdata
powershell -Command "(gc sourcechangeme.txt) -replace 'newusername', '{0}'| Out-File source1changeme.txt"
-f
userinputdata

I've tried to move the -f operator right behind the variable but it's still the same. it brakes both lines to 2 more with -f in the second line and the userinputdata on the 3rd line

Comment: @AndorArmos You didn't remove the `Write-Output` from your generator script. If you want to keep using `Write-Output` you must put parentheses around the formatting expression: `Write-Output ('...' -f $var)`