# Write-Host => Export to a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-1.0

I have got a script with some commands such as `Write-Host "Server1"`. How can I export it to a file?

When I tried with `script > export.txt` it didn't work.

Comment: any final solution about it?

Answer (score 26):

`Write-Host` redirects the output only to the console.

You can use `Write-Output` and redirect to a file (`> export.txt` or pipe to `Out-File export.txt`)

In the extreme case when you absolutely need to redirect all output from a script, take a look to this cmdlet:

```
Start-Transcript
Get-Help Start-Transcript -full
```

Answer (score 12):

In PowerShell `script > export.txt` is syntactic sugar for `script | Out-File -path export.txt`.

Write-Host sends the objects to the host, and it does not return any objects. This means no objects are piped to the Out-File cmdlet and nothing is written to the export.txt file. A workaround (in case you don't want to change your script) is to open a `cmd` console and redirect the PowerShell output using cmd console redirection.

```
C:\> powershell .\script.ps1 > .\export.txt
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that there is an Exchange command which is : Get-MailboxServer

C:\>powershell .\script.ps1 > .\export.txt

The term 'Get-MailboxServer' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable 
program, or script file. Verify the term and try again.

Thanks

Comment: Try to connect to your exchange remote runspace configuration in the beginning of your script. `$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://$computername/powershell; import-pssession $session`. In case you have problems doing this, consider opening a new question as this problem is unrelated to the initial problem.

Comment: Tried to update the answer, but got "Suggested edit queue is full"...  `-path` should be `-FilePath`

Answer (score 7):

The usefulness of different approaches is largely going to be based on your use case, of course, but...

The "right" way to do this, I believe, if you have control of the scripts (and this is what I usually do, though admittedly I was looking for a shortcut today), is to **"overload" `Write-Host`**, so to speak, **and then send everything you would've sent to `Write-Host` to this new function.**

Just to stay with valid PowerShell verbs, I call mine `Write-Feedback`.

```
function Write-Feedback()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$msg,
        [string]$BackgroundColor = "Yellow",
        [string]$ForegroundColor = "Black"
    )

    process {
        $msg | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host `
                -BackgroundColor $BackgroundColor `
                -ForegroundColor $ForegroundColor `
                $_;
        }
    }
}
```

So now you have a function that operates essentially identically to `Write-Host`, but you can easily control where the output goes. If you need to write to a file, you can edit `Write-Feedback` so that all of its calls now do whatever you need.

You could simply change the line to `Write-Output`, depending on if you're doing anything else down the pipeline...

```
...
Write-Output $_;
```

You could send the output to the same file that you're piping the rest of the command to, but within the `Write-Feedback` function, even keeping the `Write-Host` too:

```
function Write-Feedback()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$msg,
        [string]$BackgroundColor = "Yellow",
        [string]$ForegroundColor = "Black"
    )

    process {
        $msg | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host `
                -BackgroundColor $BackgroundColor `
                -ForegroundColor $ForegroundColor `
                $_;

            $_ | Out-File "./export.txt" -Append; # <<< or add a param to location
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you have a few outliers where you don't want the `Write-Feedback` content to be piped to a file, you could add a new optional parameter that asks what to do with each specific `Write-Feedback` call that you `switch` off of -- and send to file, to `Write-Host`, to `Write-Output`, etc -- changing the default to what you usually want, and explicitly `switch`ing off of the new parameter where it's explicitly set.

Etc., etc. It's just soooo much easier to route all of your calls into a centralized clearinghouse for output in PowerShell. Then when you *do* change your mind, it's not a huge search and replace -- and replace back -- task.

I think the only pain here would be if you didn't want to send things down the pipeline, so `Write-Output` is out, but did want to ensure the file `Write-Feedback` wrote to was the same as what you've specified in the `> export.txt` from your example without editing `Write-Feedback` each time. I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do that.

But since you'd then already be one step removed from your "pipe step", that's probably not a legitimate use case.

Anyhow, the bottom line is to overload `Write-Host` and do whatever you want by editing in one place.

Answer (score 3):

Using *> instead of > works for me. It redirects all output to a file; nothing is displayed on the screen.