# Combine Different ASCII Text with Same Line

Tags: html, css, powershell

I want to display my ascii text which has different lengths **on the same line within a same alignment**, Maybe **CSS or HTML** knowledge is needed but I have no knowledge and I could not achieve my purpose :/ how can I do this? Is it possible?

```
$ascii1=@'
                                    ▓▓▓▓░░░░░░▓▓▓▓                                      
                                ▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▓▓██                                  
                            ▒▒▒▒▓▓▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒                              
                        ████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒██                            
                    ████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░░░░██                          
                ▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░██                        
            ██▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░██                      
        ████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒████▓▓▓▓██░░░░░░░░██                      
      ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░░████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██░░░░██░░██                      
    ██░░▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░░████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██░░████░░██                      
    ██░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░░████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██░░██░░░░██                      
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██░░░░▒▒░░██                      
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░░████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██░░▒▒░░░░██                      
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██░░░░██░░██                      
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██░░████░░██                      
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██░░████░░██                      
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓▒▒░░░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██░░██░░░░██                      
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██░░░░░░░░██                      
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██░░░░░░░░██                      
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓████░░░░░░████                        
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓████░░░░░░████▒▒██                        
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓████░░░░░░▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▒▒██████                    
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓████░░░░░░▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▒▒████░░░░░░▓▓                  
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▓▓░░░░░░▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▒▒████░░░░░░▓▓▓▓██                  
    ████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██▓▓▓▓████░░░░░░████▒▒▒▒▒▒████░░░░░░████░░░░░░██                
      ██████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░████░░░░░░████▒▒▒▒▒▒████░░░░░░████░░░░████░░░░██              
    ██▒▒▒▒▒▒████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░████▒▒▒▒▒▒██▓▓░░░░░░████░░░░████░░░░▓▓░░░░██            
    ██████▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓██░░░░░░░░▓▓██▒▒▒▒▒▒████░░░░░░▓▓██░░░░▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░██░░░░▓▓          
    ██░░░░████▒▒▒▒▒▒████████▒▒▒▒▒▒████░░░░░░██▓▓░░░░████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██░░░░██        
    ██░░░░░░░░████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒████░░░░░░████░░░░████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██░░░░██      
    ██░░░░░░░░░░░░████████████░░░░░░████░░░░██▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██░░░░██    
  ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░████░░░░████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██░░░░██  
  ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░████░░░░████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░████░░░░██████
  ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▓▓░░██░░░░██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▓▓▓▓░░░░▓▓▓▓░░░░██
  ████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▓▓░░░░░░██░░░░██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░████░░░░████░░░░░░░░██
      ████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▓▓░░░░░░░░██░░░░██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░████░░░░████░░░░░░░░░░░░██
          ████░░░░░░░░░░▓▓░░░░░░░░░░██░░░░██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░████░░░░████░░░░░░░░░░░░████  
              ████░░░░░░▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░██░░░░██░░░░░░░░████░░░░████░░░░░░░░░░░░████      
                  ▓▓██░░▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██░░░░▓▓░░▓▓▓▓░░░░▓▓██░░░░░░░░░░░░████          
                      ██▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▓▓░░░░██░░▒▒▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░▓▓██              
                        ░░▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒░░░░░░░░░░▓▓▒▒░░                
                              ████░░░░░░░░░░▒▒████░░░░░░░░░░░░████                      
                                  ████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░████                          
                                      ████░░░░░░░░░░░░████                              
                                          ▓▓▓▓░░░░▓▓██                                  
                                          ░░░░▓▓▓▓░░                                    


'@
```

```
$ascii2=@'
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111¶¶¶111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111¶¶¶¶11111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111¶¶¶¶1111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶1111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶1111¶¶¶11¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111
111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111111111
11111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111111111111
11111111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1111
1111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1111111111
111111111111111¶¶¶111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1111111
111111111111¶¶¶¶¶11¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111111
11111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1¶¶1111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11¶¶¶¶¶1111
1111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111¶11111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111¶¶¶¶111
11111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1111¶¶¶11
1111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111111111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111¶¶1
11111¶¶¶¶¶111111111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111111
1111111¶1111111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1111111
1111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1111111
111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11¶¶¶¶¶1111111
11111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1111¶¶¶¶¶1111111
11111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111111¶¶¶¶1111111
111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111111111¶¶¶¶1111111
1111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111111111¶¶¶¶1111111
111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111¶¶¶¶¶¶111111111111111¶¶¶11111111
11¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1111111111111111111111111111¶¶111111111
1¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111111111111111¶¶1111111111111111111111
¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111111111111111111111¶¶¶¶11111111111111111
¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1¶¶¶111111111111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶11111111111111
¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11¶¶11111111111111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1111111111
¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111¶111111111111¶¶¶11111¶¶¶¶111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111111
¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111111111111111¶¶¶11111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111111
¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1111
¶1¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11
¶¶11¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1
1¶11¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶
1111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶
1111¶¶¶¶¶1¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111111111111¶¶¶¶¶
11111¶¶¶11111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111111111111¶¶
1111¶¶¶11111111¶¶¶1¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶11111¶¶¶¶¶11111111111111111¶¶
1111¶¶¶111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶1111111¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶111111111111¶
11111¶¶1111111111111111111¶¶¶¶¶1111111111111111111111111¶
111111¶11111111111111111111¶¶¶¶11111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111¶¶¶11111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111¶¶11111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
'@
```

```
$ascii3=@'
 ______________
||            ||
||            ||
||            ||
||            ||
||____________||
|______________|
 \\############\\
  \\############\\
   \      ____    \   
    \_____\___\____\

'@
```

---

**Unexpected Result**

```
write-host "$ascii1 + $ascii2 + $ascii3"
```

---

**Expected Illustration [option-1]** (all text with same line + same length)
[image]

**Expected Illustration [option-2]** (all text with same line + different length but centered)
[image]

---

**Illustration** (this is not imported, just a combine1+2)
[image]

Comment: may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57681322/how-to-output-multiple-variables-in-one-line) will answer your question . let be know if any ?

Comment: Use Write-Host :  write-host $ascii2

Comment: Could you hand-draw your expected result for reference and add it to your post?  I *think* you mean you want the images rendered side-by-side from left to right, but there's some room for mis-intepretation in your question so a concrete example of the expected output would be helpful...

Comment: I added an illustration for my purposes. Thank u all

Comment: not worked :/ @Rainysidewalks

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not 100% sure what you want, but assuming the expected result is the images side by side horizontally, and centered vertically like so:

[image: ![enter image description here]

then this script will work:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest";

# split each image into lines and pad them to a consistent lwngth
$padded = @( $ascii1, $ascii2, $ascii3 ) `
    | foreach-object {
        $lines = $_.Split("`n");
        $width = ($lines | foreach-object { $_.Length } | measure-object -Max).Maximum;
        return [pscustomobject] @{ 
            "Width" = $width
            "Lines" = $lines.PadRight($width, " ")
        };
    }

# find the number of lines in the tallest image
$height = ($padded | foreach-object { $_.Lines.Length } | measure-object -Max).Maximum;

# find the start line for each image so they're centered vertically
$padded | foreach-object {
    $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Start" -NotePropertyValue ([int](($height - $_.Lines.Length) / 2))
}

# concatenate lines from each image from left to right
$joined = for($i = 0; $i -lt $height; $i++) {
    $lines = foreach($image in $padded) {
        if( ($i -ge $image.Start) -and ($i -lt ($image.Start + $image.Lines.Length)) ) { $image.Lines[$i - $image.Start] } else { "".PadRight($image.Width, " ") }
    }
    $lines -join "  "
}

# join lines into a single string
$result = $joined -join "`r`n";

write-host $result;
```

I've tested it for PowerShell 7+ - you might need to adapt a couple of bits of it if you want to use Windows PowerShell 5.1...

Comment: lengths are not same for example, all height will be same with ascii3, or all them will same center with same line something like that

Comment: the closest answer so far can be considered correct mclayton's.... I've already set an example for this... once they are put together in a single line, the dimensions will be the same.
If this is not possible, after they are all lined up on the same line, they will be centered according to their size on the corresponding line.

Comment: Thank u for feedback, I rewrite my post and put some other illustration for this @mclayton

Comment: Yes similar like that, also is it possible all dimension with same height?

Comment: In addition for ps5, ı got an error like; Measure-Object : The property "Length" cannot be found in the input for any objects.

Comment: I think something was wrong -mclayton, my output is here [ink](https://imageupload.io/kXTfTlpFhG4VN5E)

Comment: Try again now. Also, i'm going to delete my old comments to clean up - i suggest you do the same...

Comment: By the way still it is same result Are sure it is working on ps v5? -mcbayton