# Write output of powershell script to a file (local directory)

Tags: powershell, file, output

I'm not very knowledgeable with PowerShell, but I was wondering how you could write the output of the script (excerpt below) to a file in my local directory, instead of to the screen?

```
{
    $userEntry = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
    Write-Host "User Name = " $userEntry.name
    foreach ($SPN in $userEntry.servicePrincipalName)
    {
        Write-Host "SPN = " $SPN       
    }
    Write-Host ""    
}
```

Comment: I commend your attention to the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6) and [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlets, and also [Microsoft Docs on PowerShell redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output something in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038181/how-to-output-something-in-powershell)

Comment: @akokskis - Definitely closely related; I'm not sure I'd class it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Write-Host` with [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6) with the `-Append` parameter:

```
{
    $userEntry = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
    "User Name = $($userEntry.name)" | Out-File Output.txt -Append
    foreach ($SPN in $userEntry.servicePrincipalName)
    {
        "SPN = $SPN" | Out-File Output.txt -Append
    }
    "" | Out-File Output.txt -Append  
}
```

`Out-File` will write straight to the file, the [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-6) will output both to the screen **and** to the file.

Comment: Hello HAL9256. I tried your code, but get the following error:

Comment: Unexpected token 'userEntry' in expression or statement.

+ "User Name = "$userEntry <<<< .name | Out-File Output.txt -Append
      + CategoryInfo      :ParserError: <userEntry:String> [], ParseException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Agh. I forgot to add a `+` so that it should be: `"User Name = " + $userEntry.name` The other way (imo better way) to do it is to wrap the object in a `$()` and put it inside the string, as you can better control the formatting. I have edited the Answer to show this method.

Comment: Worked like a charm!!!!!! Much thanks HAL9256!!!! Take care. Cheers, John.