# Capturing the output of a very simple power shell script

Tags: c#, powershell

I would like to execute and capture the output of a very simple powershell script.
Its a "Hello World" script and it looks like this. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments) post for reference

```
filename:C:\scripts\test.ps1

Write-Host "Hello, World"
```

Now I would like to execute that script using C# so I am doing this

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = runspace;
ps.Commands.AddScript(filename);
Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
```

Now when I run this code, I get nothing in results. Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: An even more on-point duplicate: [How to output something in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2038181/3744182).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get nothing in results

The primary reason you are not getting anything in results is because **you are writing out to the host using** [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-6), this is *wrong*.

```
 Write-Host "Hello, World"
```

Instead you need to [Write-Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-6)

```
 Write-Output "Hello, World"
```

You can also do (if it's the last item in the pipeline):

```
 "Hello, World"
```

On another note, your code can be reduced to:

```
 PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
 ps.Commands.AddScript("scriptPath");
 Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
```

You don't need to create a `Runspace` either if you are not really dealing with parallel tasks...

Comment: Good answer, but note that the implicit output feature (`"Hello, World"` vs. explicit `Write-Output "Hello, World"`) is unrelated to the whether it is used in the _last_ pipeline segment