# Powershell echo equivalent

Tags: powershell

I want to echo output to Powershell stdout. The suggested methods of using Write-Host (Debug/Versbose) writes to console as expected but when I redirect the output to a file with >> it keeps writing to the console.

What is the full equivalient to "echo" in Powershell? Echo works but the use of it is discouraged from my code editor (VS Code).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Echo equivalent in PowerShell for script testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707646/echo-equivalent-in-powershell-for-script-testing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to output something in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038181/how-to-output-something-in-powershell)

Comment: @Cililing This isn't a good dupe, because the accepted answer deals only with outputting something to the console / debug / verbose streams. OP requires that output be redirectable which requires output to the success stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` in PowerShell is just an alias to `Write-Output`, and you can always use it instead of its alias.

The reason why Visual Studio Code discouraged you to use `echo` is just because that aliases will downgrade you code's readibility.